# [minimal] option for CV

Tags: programming, options

I've been thinking of implementing an option for my CV where it extracts a set of predefined sections (in a minimal form) and typesets that instead of the entire list of everything I've done in my life.

How can I go about implementing this? I just need an example of how my code should look like, e.g.,

for my Talks sections, the minimal option would remove the authors, but would keep only the title of the talk and the venue.

At the same time, it would be nice to modify the margins, to squeeze more info onto pages.

I'm thinking that it will involve some ifthenelse options? If [minimal], \ignore{\authors} or something of the sort.

Can someone give me example code to steer me? I'm OK with messing in LaTeX, but just need guidance with starting this approach.

Comment: Do you want to create your own class or package with this option or just have a normal document with it?

Comment: Hi Martin. I can do either a separate class file or just make the use of \makeatletter \makeatother whenever necessary within the \documentclass{article}.
I think it would be easier to start my own class file and transfer what I currently have to it. Do you have suggestions?

To nabla2 and Matthew: Thanks for the suggestions, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I definitely don't want to start learning another platform (xml or yaml, etc). I'm sure it is doable in Latex, but I just need an example piece of code.

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way might be with a simple conditional. So your document would look like this:

```
\newif\ifmaximal
% \maximaltrue % Uncomment to compile big CV.
\ifmaximal
\PassOptionsToClass{article}{10pt}
\else
\PassOptionToClass{article}{12pt}
\fi
\documentclass{article} % Or whatever
\begin{document}
\ifmaximal
\section{This section won't be in the minimal}
Foo
\fi
\section{In the minimal}
Bar
\ifmaximal
Again, not in the maximal...
\fi
\end{document}
```

So anything you only want in the bigger cv goes between `\ifmaximal` and `\fi`. Note this is sort of the opposite of what you want but it should work just as well...

Comment: You can also use the `\PassOptionsToPackage` command to give different margins to `geometry` or `typearea` packages... (I'll update this when I get a chance to test it)

Answer (score 1):

If it were me I would write my full CV in XML or YAML and use a structured datatype (there are  [XML schemas](http://www.hr-xml.org/hr-xml/wms/hr-xml-1-org/index.php?language=2) in this area written by human resources IT professionals, but it might be overkill).  This way you can list each talk and indicate the title, author, date, location etc.

Then write scripts to extract the data you want and generate the desired TeX file.

Comment: Or you could write in [Markdown and export to TeX with pandoc](http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/primarily-pandoc/) or in emacs org mode and use its built in export functions. I'm not sure that answers the question about having two versions though...

Comment: There is [`yst`](https://github.com/jgm/yst) which can take a suitably structured `yaml` file and output tex. It used the above-mentioned pandoc to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

- [Your Curriculum in LaTeX](http://stefano.italians.nl/archives/date/2007/11)
- [How to write a LaTeX class file and design your own CV](http://blog.scribtex.com/how-to-write-a-latex-class-file-and-design-yo)

Comment: -1. Link only answer and both links are dead.

Comment: Same reason as above, dead links in a link only answer, therefore providing nothing of benefit.