# Conditional typesetting / build

Tags: macros, conditionals, compiling

Let's say I have .tex file which is a set of problems and solutions, of which I want to make two pdf files, one which includes the solutions and one which doesn't. so I need to build the .tex file under two different modes, and specify that parts of the document be ignored under one of the modes.

This is something common in programming context. e.g. in `C++` i can code

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  // do this additional stuff ...
#endif
```

How can I do something equivalent in latex?

Comment: Perhaps see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3089/how-do-i-conditionally-execute-something-based-on-a-documentclass-option

Answer (score 84, accepted):

[As I mentioned here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16711/minimal-option-for-cv/21642#21642), the simplest way might be conditionals:

```
\newif\ifanswers
\answerstrue % comment out to hide answers
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Question
\ifanswers
Answer
\fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great solution! Is there a simple way, by keeping your current method, to have answers automatically in red color (if `\answerstrue`, if not answers are hidden)?

Comment: Define for example`\newcommand\answer{\ifanswers\color{red}}` `\let\endanswer\fi` and then use `\begin{answer}...\end{answer}`

Comment: Btw, I've been using `mdframed` for this. For example `\newmdenv[linecolor=cyan, linewidth=1mm, backgroundcolor=black!4, topline=false, bottomline=false, skipabove=5mm, skipbelow=3mm, innertopmargin=3mm, innerbottommargin=3mm]{solution}` and `\ifanswers\else\let\solution\comment \let\endsolution\endcomment\fi`

Comment: I get an error when trying this:

`\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{comment}

\newif\ifanswers
%\answerstrue % Commenting this out gives an error message:
% File ended while scanning use of \next.


\newmdenv[linecolor=cyan, linewidth=1mm, backgroundcolor=black!4, topline=false, bottomline=false, skipabove=5mm, skipbelow=3mm, innertopmargin=3mm, innerbottommargin=3mm]{solution}

\ifanswers\else\let\solution\comment \let\endsolution\endcomment\fi

\begin{document}
 
\begin{solution}
S
\end{solution}

\end{document}`

Comment: In short: without color the original tip works fine, but the coloring described in comments does not.

Answer (score 97):

There are numerous ways to do this.

One way is to use `\ifdefined`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\newcommand*{\DEBUG}{}%
\begin{document}
\ifdefined\DEBUG
    DEBUG was on
\else
   DEBUG was off
\fi
\end{document}
```

---

Another is to use a `\newtoggle` defined by [the `etoolbox` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{DEBUG}
\toggletrue{DEBUG}
%\togglefalse{DEBUG}

\begin{document}
\iftoggle{DEBUG}{
    DEBUG was on
}{
   DEBUG was off
}
\end{document}
```

The same pacakge also provides a `newbool` with similar functionality:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newbool{DEBUG}
\booltrue{DEBUG}
%\boolfalse{DEBUG}

\begin{document}
\ifbool{DEBUG}{
    DEBUG was on
}{
   DEBUG was off
}
\end{document}
```

See [Difference between \newbool and \newtoggle from etoolbox package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101076/difference-between-newbool-and-newtoggle-from-etoolbox-package) for a discussion of these two.

---

Another is to use [the `xstring` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\DEBUG}{ON}%

\begin{document}
\IfStrEq{\DEBUG}{ON}{
    DEBUG was on
}{
    DEBUG was off
}
\end{document}
```

---

Or use [the `ifthen` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifthen). But do make a note of [Why is the ifthen package obsolete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13866/why-is-the-ifthen-package-obsolete) if considering this solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{\DEBUG}{ON}%

\begin{document}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\DEBUG}{ON}}{
    DEBUG was on
}{
    DEBUG was off
}
\end{document}
```

---

Over time I have used all the options (and stayed away from `xifthen` due to comments at link regarding that this package is obsolete), but tend to gravitate to `\ifdefined` when doing quick tests, and use `etoolbox` approach for more longer term solutions for on/off conditions, and the `xstring` approach when there are more conditions to consider.

As @Seamus mentions there is a `\newif` built in, but I have tended to avoid that as I did not like the syntax and had to look it up every time, but that is just a personal preference

Comment: In your first example, why are you not simply use `\newif\ifdebug`, `\debugtrue` or `\debugfalse` and then use `\ifdebug`?

Comment: @MartinScharrer: That solution is covered in Seamus's answer, but I can never remember the syntax of `\newif` so just got used to `\ifdefined`.

Comment: Keep in mind that using the \ifdefined method will not be able to work as an include guard.

Comment: @dionyziz: Can you elaborate? Not sure I understand what you mean by "include guard" and if it is what I think then why it would not work?

Comment: @PeterGrill When you do something like \ifdefined\DEBUG\import{xxx.tex}\fi, then this import is always done – meaning if you're importing packages with conflicting names (e.g. defining different proof envs) based on DEBUG, it won't work with a "redefined" error.

Comment: `\ifdefined` is nice when you want to do one thing when processing a file (e.g. for a chapter) separately, rather than when you are putting all the files together in one document using `\input` or `\include`.

Answer (score 12):

The other answers address the general case. In relation to the specific problem that you describe in which you want to typeset Questions and Answers, you might like to consider the `answers` package which does all of the hard work for you.

**MWE**

I've set up a `problem` and `shortsolution` environment in what follows- the `answers` package writes the `shortsolution` to the file `shortsolutions.tex`, which is then included at the end of the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{answers} 
%\usepackage[nosolutionfiles]{answers}        % use this line if you want to see the answers 
                                                                                        % in the document

\newcounter{problem}
\newenvironment{problem}{\refstepcounter{problem} {\bfseries\theproblem}.\ }{}
% solution files
\Opensolutionfile{shortsolutions}
\Newassociation{shortsolution}{shortSoln}{shortsolutions}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
Here's a question
     \begin{shortsolution}
      Here's the answer- can put anything in here: e.g $\frac{1}{3}$
     \end{shortsolution}
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
Here's another question
     \begin{shortsolution}
      Here's another answer- can put figures, tables- anything you like!
     \end{shortsolution}
\end{problem}
\newpage

% close the solutions files
\Closesolutionfile{shortsolutions}

% input the SHORT solutions file
\IfFileExists{shortsolutions.tex}{\input{shortsolutions.tex}}{}

\end{document}
```

If you toggle the lines

```
%\usepackage{answers} 
\usepackage[nosolutionfiles]{answers}        % use this line if you want to see the answers
```

then the answers will be displayed with the questions.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 10):

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/comment

From the documentation:

> [Purpose:] selectively in/exclude pieces of text: the user can define new
>   comment versions, and each is controlled separately.
>   Special comments can be defined where the user specifies the
>   action that is to be taken with each comment line.

Answer (score 7):

In ConTeXt, you can use `modes` for conditional typesetting. Modes can either be set on the command line by passing

```
context --modes=<list of modes>
```

or using `\enablemode` and `\disablemode`. You can test if a mode is set or not using `\doifmodeelse{...}{...}{...}` or using `\startmode` or `\startnotmode`.

See the [ConTeXt wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modes) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

It depends.

### For code

A normal conditional method in TeX is to use `\newif\iffoo` and use `\iffoo .. \else ... \fi` to do the test, use `\footrue` and `\foofalse` to change the state.

This is the basic conditional mechanism in both Plain TeX and LaTeX, and is used by most LaTeX packages.

It is not the LaTeX syntax, and doesn't support complex bool expressions. Then packages `ifthen`/`xifthen`, `etoolbox`, `expl3` etc. can be used to support more complex conditions. I suggest `etoolbox` or `expl3`.

### For text

Those conditions above are for general material, mostly macros and short text. However, they are not robust sometimes: you can't use unbalanced `\else`, `\fi`, `\ifXXX` in the branches, for very long text it may cause surprising errors. Then you can use `comment`, `xcomment`, `tagging` packages for longer text (but not for macros). They work in a verbatim way.

See [Document configuration via tags or labels?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10996/document-configuration-via-tags-or-labels) for `tagging` package. It is quite user-friendly.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way should be like the following,

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{problem}[1]
{\def\temp{#1}}{%
\temp% comment this line to remove the answer.
}

\begin{document}
\begin{problem}{Garbage Collector}
What is your name?
\end{problem}
\end{document}
```