# Conditional Bibliography in LyX Subdocument

Tags: bibliographies, lyx

I am using LyX to manage a multi-part document (my thesis) and I would like to be able to produce stand alone sub-documents (e.g. a chapter) that include a bibliography, but only when the sub-document is produced on its own. When I produce the full master document, the only bibliography should be at the end.

How can I make the bibliography in a LyX subdocument only show up when the document is used by itself (and not when it is included in the master document)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After experiments using the helpful tips from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build), I found an automatic solution that works:

At the top of the master thesis document add a new TeX command (using Insert>TeX Code) that identifies that we are building the complete thesis:

```
\newcommand{\FULLTHESIS}{} %Id that we are building the complete thesis
```

Then in each chapter enclose the bibliography (or any other items that should only appear when the chapter is created standalone) between two raw TeX Code blocks as follows:

```
\ifdefined\FULLTHESIS\else  %TeX way of saying if not defined FULL_THESIS
```

*Insert the Bibilography (etc) Here*

```
\fi
```

Note: I could not get some of the more elegant TeX approaches from [the post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build) such as `\newif` and the LaTeX macro `\@ifundefined` to work properly in my document under LyX.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a Branch for the subdocument only, which then contains the Bibliography. You can learn more about Branches in the Users Guide in section 6.8.

A good starting point to look at how that works is the thesis template which comes bundled with LyX (at least from v2.0 on).

Comment: Thanks for the tip... Branches do seem like a possible starting point, but they apparently still require manually selecting whether or not to include the branch text (e.g. bibilography). What I am looking for is a way to automate this such that without changing the files, the bibliography is included when run stand-alone, but not when it's a subdocument. Seems like there could be a raw LaTeX (aka ERT) solution that sets a flag in the master, and then the sub-document (chapter) could only include the text if the flag is not set. Any ideas how to do so?