# automatically insert data in a complex table

Tags: tables

I have a relatively complex table that looks like this:

[image]

The same table structure is going to be repeated so many times. I already have the tables in MS Word. My question is if there is an easy method to fill the data in the table code?

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}

%This will change the font for all the tables in the document.
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\table[ht]}{\fontsize{9pt}{10.8pt}\selectfont}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.11in}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\columncolor{Gainsboro}}c}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\centering
\caption{Experiences in practical Physics work}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|Y|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
               &            & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\emph{\textbf{\%}}} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\emph{\textbf{Comparisons}}}  \\
    \hline  \rowcolor{Gainsboro}  {\textbf{Group}}& {\textbf{N}} & \textbf{positive} & \textbf{neutral} & \textbf{negative} & \textbf{$\chi^2$} & \textbf{df} & \textbf{p} \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{Gainsboro}{\emph{Q1 (a)}} & \multicolumn{7}{Z|}{I prefer to have written instructions for experiments}  \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{PowderBlue}\emph{University group} & {150} & 73         & 7          & 20         & \multirow{2}{*}{0.9} & \multirow{2}{*}{4} & \multirow{2}{*}{ns} \\
    \cline{1-5}
    \cellcolor{YellowGreen}\emph{School group} & {150} & 70         & 8          & 22         &            &            &  \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{Gainsboro}{\emph{Q1 (b)}} & \multicolumn{7}{Z|}{Practical work helps my understanding of Physics topics}                   \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{PowderBlue}\emph{University group} & {150} & 34         & 11         & 55         & \multirow{2}{*}{3.9} & \multirow{2}{*}{4} & \multirow{2}{*}{ns} \\
    \cline{1-5}
    \cellcolor{YellowGreen}\emph{School group} & {150} & 38         & 7          & 55         &            &            &  \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{Gainsboro}{\emph{Q1 (c)}} & \multicolumn{7}{Z|}{Discussions in the laboratory enhance my understanding of the subject}                   \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{PowderBlue}\emph{University group} & {150} & 70         & 8          & 22         & \multirow{2}{*}{2.4} & \multirow{2}{*}{4} & \multirow{2}{*}{ns} \\
    \cline{1-5}
    \cellcolor{YellowGreen}\emph{School group} & {150} & 65         & 10         & 25         &            &            &  \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{Gainsboro}{\emph{Q1 (d)}} & \multicolumn{7}{Z|}{I felt confident in carrying out the experiments in Physics}                   \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{PowderBlue}\emph{University group} & {150} & 52         & 12         & 36         & \multirow{2}{*}{13.7} & \multirow{2}{*}{4} & \multirow{2}{*}{< 0.05} \\
    \cline{1-5}
    \cellcolor{YellowGreen}\emph{School group} & {150} & 44         & 15         & 41         &            &            &  \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{Gainsboro}{\emph{Q1 (e)}} & \multicolumn{7}{Z|}{The experimental procedure was clearly explained in the instructions given}                   \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{PowderBlue}\emph{University group} & {150} & 31         & 14         & 55         & \multirow{2}{*}{14.8} & \multirow{2}{*}{4} & \multirow{2}{*}{< 0.01} \\
    \cline{1-5}
    \cellcolor{YellowGreen}\emph{School group} & {150} & 46         & 11         & 43         &            &            &  \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{Gainsboro}{\emph{Q1 (f)}} & \multicolumn{7}{Z|}{I was so confused in the laboratory that I ended up following the instructions without understanding what I was doing}                   \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{PowderBlue}\emph{University group} & {150} & 63         & 12         & 25         & \multirow{2}{*}{1.1} & \multirow{2}{*}{4} & \multirow{2}{*}{ns} \\
    \cline{1-5}
    \cellcolor{YellowGreen}\emph{School group} & {150} & 65         & 9          & 26         &            &            &  \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{Gainsboro}{\emph{Q1 (g)}} & \multicolumn{7}{Z|}{There was good linkage between experiments and the relevant theory}                   \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{PowderBlue}\emph{University group} & {150} & 36         & 15         & 49         & \multirow{2}{*}{94.4} & \multirow{2}{*}{4} & \multirow{2}{*}{<0.001} \\
   \cline{1-5}
    \cellcolor{YellowGreen}\emph{School group} & {150} & 68         & 11         & 21         &            &            &  \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\label{ch7:tab:experiencesinpracticalphysics}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I know that I shouldn't be asking two questions but this one is small: How do I make an individual cell transparent?

Edit: I made it MWE and here's another table with the same structure but different data:

[image]

Comment: Please post a complete document, i.e. an example that can be actually compiled (a MWE).

Comment: The `\g@addto@macro` bit is wrong; remove `[ht]` from it as soon as possible.

Comment: I got this bit from this site, I've no idea how it works!. Yes, there wasn't `[ht]` in it but adding it makes everything work. When I remove it: 1- The word `[ht]` comes at the top of every table (because my tables are always `begin{table}[ht]`. 2- The font does NOT change 3- The positioning of the float doesn't work anymore

Comment: This kind of table format which has both column-, and row-spanning is interesting. If my memory serves, I think @egreg once mentioned he had once used intertwined `\halign`s and `\valign`s, which could accomplish this kind of format.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The biggest thing to figure out really is exactly *how* do you want to specify the data. Here I have defined a `\Data` macro that accepts four mandatory parameters:

- the text of the question,
- the label for the first group along with it's data,
- the label for the second group along with it's data, and
- the comparison data

To simplify things I decided to go with `&` separator as that is what `tabular` needs (see *Further Enhancements* below). So, for instance the first set of data is defined as:

```
\Data{I prefer to have written instructions for experiments}
    {\UGroup & 150 & 73 & 7 & 20}
    {\SGroup & 150 & 70 & 8 & 22}
    {0.9 & 4 & \NS}
```

and as you can see from this I defined macros for the labels `\UGroup` and `\SGroup`.  Specifying the data in this manner within the custom `MyTabular` environment yields:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `collcell`  package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/collcell) is used to automatically place the last three columns within a `\multirow{2}{*}{<data>}`.
- To ensure that the above mentioned `\multirow` is only applied after the header is completed, I used `newtoggle` from [the `etoolbox` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox) as I prefer that syntax versus the `\newif` syntax. But if you don't want to include an additional package it should be pretty straightforward to adapt this to use `\newif` or [some other conditional methods](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build/33577#33577)
- Defining macros `\UGroup` and `\SGroup` for labels not only makes it more readable but provides additional flexibility in case you decide to tweak it later.
- I moved your customizations of `\arraystretch` and `\fontsize` to be within the `MyTabular` environment, so that the adjustments are only have an effect within `MyTabular`.
- Two counters `QuestionCount` and `QuestionSubCount` are used to automate the labeling of the tables and each row of that data. You can adjust the formatting of these as desired.
- The `MyTabular` environment accepts an optional (i.e., within square brackets) first parameter to override the label for each row.  Defaults to `Q<n>` where `<n>` takes on increasing integer values starting at 1.

### References:

- I did not address your float issues as that is probably better explained elsewhere. See for example [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)
- You should also check out the [the `booktabs` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs) for more table formatting options.

## Further Enhancements:

- Perhaps instead of using `&` as a delimiter, a comma separated list would be preferred. However it should be noted that this is **not** at all as simple as it seems.

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newtoggle{DoneWithHeader}
\newcommand{\MyMultiRow}[1]{%
    \iftoggle{DoneWithHeader}{%
        \multirow{2}{*}{#1}% no longer in header
    }{%
        #1% still in header so do not apply \multirow
    }%
}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\collectcell\MyMultiRow}{l}<{\endcollectcell}}


\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.11in}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\columncolor{Gainsboro}}c}


\newcounter{QuestionCount}
\newcommand*{\QuestionGroup}{}
\newenvironment{MyTabular}[2][Q\arabic{QuestionCount}]{%
    % #1 = Question Group: Defaults to "Q<n>"
    % #2 = usual tabular column specification
    \stepcounter{QuestionCount}% increment for subsequent tables
    \setcounter{QuestionSubCount}{0}% ensure we start at (a) for subsequent tables
    \xdef\QuestionGroup{#1}
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \fontsize{9pt}{10.8pt}\selectfont
    \global\togglefalse{DoneWithHeader}% not yet done with header
    \begin{tabular}{#2}
        \hline% Print header rows
        & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\emph{\textbf{\%}}} & 
                \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\emph{\textbf{Comparisons}}}  \\
        \hline  
        \rowcolor{Gainsboro}  {\textbf{Group}}& {\textbf{N}} & \textbf{positive} & 
               \textbf{neutral} & \textbf{negative} & \textbf{$\chi^2$} & \textbf{df} & 
               \textbf{p} \global\toggletrue{DoneWithHeader}\\
        \hline
}{%
    \end{tabular}%
}


\newcounter{QuestionSubCount}
\newcommand*{\Data}[4]{%
    % #1 = Question Text
    % #2 = Univerity group numbers
    % #3 = School Group Numbers
    % #4 = Comparrisons
    %
    \hline
    \rowcolor{Gainsboro}{%
        \stepcounter{QuestionSubCount}
        \emph{\QuestionGroup~(\alph{QuestionSubCount})}%
    } &
    \multicolumn{7}{Z|}{#1}  \\
    \hline
    #2 & #4\\
    \cline{1-5}
    #3 &&&\\\hline
}%

\newcommand{\UGroup}{{\cellcolor{PowderBlue}\emph{University group}}}%
\newcommand{\SGroup}{{\cellcolor{YellowGreen}\emph{School group}}}%

\newcommand{\NS}{ns}%

\begin{document}
\begin{MyTabular}{|c|Y|c|c|c|M|M|M|}
    \Data{I prefer to have written instructions for experiments}
        {\UGroup & 150 & 73 & 7 & 20}
        {\SGroup & 150 & 70 & 8 & 22}
        {0.9 & 4 & \NS}
    \Data{Practical work helps my understanding of Physics topics}
        {\UGroup&150&34&11&55}
        {\SGroup&150&38&7&55}
        {3.9&4&\NS}
    \Data{Discussions in the laboratory enhance my understanding of the subject}
        {\UGroup&150&70&8&22}
        {\SGroup&150&65&10&25}
        {2.4&4&\NS}
    \Data{I felt confident in carrying out the experiments in Physics}
        {\UGroup&150&52&12&36}
        {\SGroup&150&44&15&41}
        {13.7&4&\NS}
    \Data{The experimental procedure was clearly explained in the instructions given}
        {\UGroup&150&31&14&55}
        {\SGroup&150&46&11&43}
        {14.8&4&\NS}
    \Data{I was so confused in the laboratory that I ended up following the instructions without understanding what I was doing}
        {\UGroup&150&63&12&25}
        {\SGroup&150&65&9&26}
        {1.1&4&\NS}
    \Data{There was good linkage between experiments and the relevant theory}
        {\UGroup&150&36&15&49}
        {\SGroup&150&68&11&21}
        {94.4&4&$<0.001$}
\end{MyTabular}

\bigskip\bigskip

\begin{MyTabular}{|c|Y|c|c|c|M|M|M|}
    \Data{Is practucal work useful}
        {\UGroup&150&41&31&28}
        {\SGroup&150&41&32&27}
        {14.8&4&\NS}
    \Data{Is practucal work helpful}
        {\UGroup&150&45&25&30}
        {\SGroup&150&47&23&30}
        {14.8&4&\NS}
\end{MyTabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow :D, I wish I can up vote the answer many times. Thanks a lot

Comment: Wow indeed. SE needs this quality of reply.

Comment: @ForkrulAssail and Abdulhaq Elhouderi: Thanks for the kind words.

Comment: @AbdulhaqElhouderi: Have updated to fix a bug, prior version was not resetting one of the counters.