# grouping data by columns

Tags: formatting, columns

I have these three graphics all in one line. Now I would like to have 3 columns with their respective data aligned underneath them (the alignment underneath the graphics does not really matter).

This is what I have:

```
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}
\item (1)(2)(3) 
\item(1,2)(3) 
\item(1,3)(2) 
\item(2,3)(1) 
\item(1, 2, 3) 
\item(1, 3, 2)
\item(1)(2)(3)(4)
\item(1,3)(2)(4)
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
```

How can I specify which column each \item goes into? For example, I want column 1 to contain everything except the last 2 \items and column 2 to contain the last 2 \items. (I did not include all the data in this post)

How can I format this data into three columns and specify which column they shall be placed in?

Comment: Perhaps the approach you are suggesting right now it's not the best one (specially if there's no particular order for the items of each column); perhaps you could use three side-by-side `minipage`s and place one `enumearte` environment in each one of the `minipage`s?

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you provided some example as I am not clear on what you are trying to accomplish.  If you could show what you want instead of describing it that would probably greatly clarify things.

Comment: Was my answer below of any help, or did I totally misunderstand the question?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this is another case (see References below for the earlier case) where the most important thing to figure out really is exactly *how* do you want to specify which items you want printed.  So, here is *one* way where you can specify which rows of the data end up in each of the columns.

1. Define the enumerated list in a macro so that it can be reused.  In this you call `\MyItem{}` and pass in the parameter as the data:

   ```
   \begin{enumerate}%
       \MyItem{(1)(2)(3)}
       \MyItem{(1,2)(3)}
       \MyItem{(1,3)(2)}
       \MyItem{(2,3)(1)}
       \MyItem{(1, 2, 3)}
       \MyItem{(1, 3, 2)}
       \MyItem{(1)(2)(3)(4)}
       \MyItem{(1,3)(2)(4)}
   \end{enumerate}%
   ```

   This is part of the definition of the macro `\MyEnumeratedList` which has some initialization before this list.
2. Now wherever you want to use this `enumerated` list, you simply specify which rows you actually want printed.  So if you only want rows 2, 5 and 7 to be printed, you say:

   ```
   \MyEnumeratedList{2,5,7}
   ```

Any row not specified in this list is not printed.

So, with the data provided, I have printed the rows as specified in the question. Column 3 was not specified so I chose rows 2, 5, and 7 for that column:

[image]

### Notes:

- I assumed that the list was to be numbered consecutively from 1 for each of the columns.  If this is not desired using another counter to number then would preserve the numbering of the items across the three columns.
- I used three `minipages` to display the three columns, as suggested by Gonzalo Medina in the comments.  The `multicols` approach is not the way to achieve the desired result.
- There is an assumption here that *at least* one row will be printed in each column. Otherwise you will end up with the error message:

  > LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

  This could occur if you provide much larger numbers than the total number of rows.

### Further Enchantments:

- Handle the case where none of the rows are printed.
- Provide for greater flexibility in how the rows are to be printed. For example a better way to have specified the first column in the example provided would have been:

  ```
  \MyEnumeratedList{1,...,6}
  ```

### References:

- Another answer where it the main problem was really to figure out how to specify what you want: [automatically insert data in a complex table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70322/automatically-insert-data-in-a-complex-table/74588#74588).

  So for these type of questions it would be helpful if the person asking the question considered first: *How do I want to specify what I want?*

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcounter{RowCounter}
\newcommand*{\ListOfRowsToDisplay}{}%
\newcommand*{\MyItem}[1]{%
    % #1 = comma separated list of which rows to show
    % #2 = item data
    \stepcounter{RowCounter}%
    % Add extra commas on what we are searching for and what we are searching in.
    % Hence, to check if the number (for example), six is in the string we
    % search for ",6,".  This will prevent the returning of a false positive
    % when the number 6 is not in the sting, but the digit 6 is used as part of a
    % number.  Say the search string is "23,25,26,27", now searching for ",6,"
    % will result in not found, but searching for "6" would have resulted in the
    % string being found.
    \StrPosition{\ListOfRowsToDisplay}{,\arabic{RowCounter},}[\PositionInString]
    \IfEq{\PositionInString}{0}{%
        % This row number is not to be printed and we keep movin on
    }{%
        % This is a row that needs to be printed
        \item #1
    }%
}%
\newcommand*{\MyEnumeratedList}[1]{%
    % #1 = comma separated list of which rows to show
    \setcounter{RowCounter}{0}% reset as we are starting over
    % Save the list of rows globally so to make the enumerated list easier to read
    \xdef\ListOfRowsToDisplay{,#1,}%
    \begin{enumerate}%
        \MyItem{(1)(2)(3)}
        \MyItem{(1,2)(3)}
        \MyItem{(1,3)(2)}
        \MyItem{(2,3)(1)}
        \MyItem{(1, 2, 3)}
        \MyItem{(1, 3, 2)}
        \MyItem{(1)(2)(3)(4)}
        \MyItem{(1,3)(2)(4)}
    \end{enumerate}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.30\linewidth}%
    \MyEnumeratedList{1,2,3,4,5,6}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.30\linewidth}%
    \MyEnumeratedList{7,8}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.30\linewidth}%
    \MyEnumeratedList{2,5,7}
\end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```