# How to frame/shade a whole section?

Tags: sectioning, framed, mdframed

Simple Question, but it seems to tricky for me. I don't know how to redefine the sectioning in a way, that the whole content (incl. subsections, ...) assigned to one `\section{...}` command would be framed and/or shaded by `framed`/`mdframed`. Even various tries and after hours of searching, I've honestly no clue how to handle that and would be very glad about some help.

BTW: I'm looking for a solution with no dependencies on packages like titlesec or similars... just a clean redefinition if possible. =)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  A simple `\begin{mdframed}...\end{mdframed}` with the content you want framed placed within seems to work.  Perhaps this is a good case where it would help if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem you are having.

Comment: @Peter Grill Well, it is not my ambition to handle that manually, otherwise there were no need for questioning. On the other hand, how should I do a MWE if I don't know where to redefine the sectioning? All reference points I know so far is \section{} and it only modifies the title - thats it.

Comment: @triton: In this case you could mock-up exactly how you would like your main document to look. If I understood the question, a MWE could be `\documentclass{article}` followed by everything in my answer from `\begin{document}` to `\end{document}`.  Then your intent would be clearer.  Basically try to show what you want as opposed to just describing it.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the comments, it seems that you want to be able to set a particular section to be framed or not, without having to locate the end of that section to insert an additional command.  One way to do this is to use `\FramedSection` as defined below instead of the normal `\section`.

The `\FramedSection` start a `\begin{mdframed}` and sets `WithinFramedSection` to be true so that we know that this framed section needs to be closed upon a subsequent `\FramedSection`, or a normal `\section`.

The closing of this `mdframed` environment is done via a call to `\EndFramedIfNeeded`.  This is needed upon:

- a subsequent `\FramedSection`
- a subsequent `\section`
- and at the end of the document

### Notes:

- I have used `newtoggle` from [the `etoolbox` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox) as I prefer that syntax versus the `\newif` syntax. But if you don't want to include an additional package it should be pretty straightforward to adapt this to use `\newif` or [some other conditional methods](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build/33577#33577).
- [The `lipsum` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) was used just to provide dummy text. It is not needed in your document.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtoggle{WithinFramedSection}%
\togglefalse{WithinFramedSection}%

\let\OldSection\section%
\def\section{\EndFramedIfNeeded\OldSection}%
\newcommand*{\EndFramedIfNeeded}{%
    \iftoggle{WithinFramedSection}{%
        \global\togglefalse{WithinFramedSection}%
        \end{mdframed}% End previous framed section
    }{}%
}%
\newcommand*{\FramedSection}[1]{%
    \EndFramedIfNeeded%
    \global\toggletrue{WithinFramedSection}%
    \begin{mdframed}\OldSection{#1}%
}%

% If the last \section is a \FramedSection, we need to end
% the mdframed environment.
\AtEndDocument{\EndFramedIfNeeded}%


\begin{document}
\FramedSection{Framed Section Name 1}
\subsection{Framed Sub section name 1}
\lipsum[1]
%
\section{Unframed Section}
\lipsum[2]
%
\FramedSection{Framed Section Name 2}
\subsection{Framed Sub section name 2}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much, I always thought I just could modify the title with \section{\@startsection{..}}.