# Writing a macro in LaTeX for getting a vector i,j,k representation by passing parameters

Tags: macros, vector

I want to create a newcommand `\vecty` to create a vector which will take 3 parameters
like `\vecty{1}{2}{3}` and this should display as `$\hat{i}+2\hat{j}+3\hat{k}$`
and if I give `\vecty{0}{3}{-3}` then it should show `$3\hat{j}-3\hat{k}`.

I am using LaTeX. I would appreciate any guidance that comes how to get through it. 
I did try `\ifthenelse` code but it turned to be quite hefty. 
You can have a look at [the code](https://sites.google.com/site/mathematicsteaching/lyx/gettheunitvectorinx-y-zspaceusingamacroinlatex/vecty.tex?attredirects=0&d=1).

But I know that the code is too bad. Hence wanted to understand if there are other ways to implement it. Kindly help I m a newbie.

Comment: in my opinion, it is more beautiful if a vector is made in bold face rather than with a hat (in printed version).

Comment: Would you please specify the range of numbers that can appear in the arguments? Do you expect decimal numbers and fractions, for instance?

Comment: Yes there are going to be fractional numbers that might be passed as 1/2, 2/3 or 3.4 etc.
Also there might be values like \vecty{0}{1}{0} which i expect to get me just \hat{j}

Answer (score 20):

Here is one way you can do this:

[image]

### Notes:

- This updated version properly handles *integer and decimal* coefficients of zero (+0, 0.00) or one with leading `+` signs, spurious spaces, and non-numbers in the input (as per the second section of the table above).
- `newtoggle` from [the `etoolbox` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox) was used as I prefer that syntax versus the `\newif` syntax. But if you don't want to include an additional package it should be pretty straightforward to adapt this to use `\newif` or [some other conditional methods](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build/33577#33577).  This toggle keeps track if a term has already been printed to ensure that a leading positive term does not have a `+`.
- I used [the `xstring` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/) to determine if the number had a leading minus sign, or was zero, but again, this could easily be adapted to not use that package as well.
- I would recommend that you use this macro as `$\vecty$` - that is you explicitly enter math mode, as used below. If however, you wish to use it without having to enter math mode as per your original question, you should *not* surround it with dollar signs, but instead use

  `\ensuremath{\LeadingSign #1 #2}`

  as then it will be useable inside or outside of math mode. To repeat, I am **not** recommending this as this is clearly a math mode macro.  Please see [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro) if you disagree.

### Further Enhancements:

- Should `\vecty` be required to typeset more than three components, one can easily add additional calls to `\Display{}{}` for each of the components -- no other changes should be required.  Note that this has not been tested.
- This does not remove the coefficient equal to one, nor eliminate the term if the coefficient is zero for the case of non numerical input: For example `\vecty{-1x}{+0y}{1z}`.
- Could use `pgf` math to do numerical processing of the input so that basic expressions in the coefficients could be simplified. The `pgf` math functions could also be used to convert `-0.5` to `-\frac{1}{2}`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*{\LeadingSign}{}%
\newcommand*{\CleanedCoefficientWithNoSpaces}{}% coefficient with spaces & "+" removed
\newcommand*{\CleanedCoefficient}{}% digit "1" removed if coefficient is 1, or -1

\newcommand*{\Display}[2]{%
    % #1 = coefficient (may not be a number)
    % #2 = paramater
    %
    % ---------------------------------------------------------------- Clean input
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{ }{}[\CoefficientWithNoSpaces]% eliminate any spaces
    \IfBeginWith{\CoefficientWithNoSpaces}{+}{% eliminate any leading + sign
        \StrSubstitute{\CoefficientWithNoSpaces}{+}{}[\CleanedCoefficientWithNoSpaces]%
    }{%
        \renewcommand*{\CleanedCoefficientWithNoSpaces}{\CoefficientWithNoSpaces}%
    }%
    % ---------------------------------------------------------------- 1, +1, -1 issue
    % If the coefficient is 1, +1, or -1, we need to supress the digit
    \IfEq{\CleanedCoefficientWithNoSpaces}{1}{% coefficient equivalent to +1
        \renewcommand*{\CleanedCoefficient}{}%  eliminate the digit
    }{%
        \IfEq{\CoefficientWithNoSpaces}{-1}{% coefficient equivalent to -1
            \renewcommand*{\CleanedCoefficient}{-}% eliminate the digit (leave sign)
        }{%
            % This is the case of the coefficient not being +1, or -1, so use as is
            \renewcommand*{\CleanedCoefficient}{\CleanedCoefficientWithNoSpaces}% 
            %
            % The issue of the leading sign is dealt with below.  Could have moved the
            % leading sign handling here (with some adjustments above), but that would 
            % have made the code a little harder to read. There is already enough  
            % illiteracy in the world. :-)
        }%
    }%
    % ----------------------------------------------------------------  Leading sign
    % We don't want a + sign for the very first term printed.
    \renewcommand*{\LeadingSign}{}% initalize
    \IfBeginWith{\CleanedCoefficientWithNoSpaces}{-}{%
        % use default empty value (sign is part of number)
        % or for the case of -1, this has already been set above
    }{%
        \iftoggle{PrintedFirstTerm}{%
            \renewcommand*{\LeadingSign}{+}%
        }{%
            % Since a leading term of this vector has not yet been printed 
            % we do not add a + sign
        }%
    }%
    % ----------------------------------------------------------------  Print
    \IfEq{#1}{0}{}{%
        \LeadingSign \CleanedCoefficient #2%
        \global\toggletrue{PrintedFirstTerm}% so next term can have + sign
    }%
}%

\newtoggle{PrintedFirstTerm}
\newcommand*{\vecty}[3]{%
    \global\togglefalse{PrintedFirstTerm}%
    \Display{#1}{\hat{i}} %
    \Display{#2}{\hat{j}}%
    \Display{#3}{\hat{k}}%
    \iftoggle{PrintedFirstTerm}{}{\mathbf{0}}% could also use \vec{0} here
}%

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{ll}
  \verb|$\vecty{1}{2}{3}$|        & \vecty{1}{2}{3}  \\
  \verb|$\vecty{0}{3}{-3}$|       & \vecty{0}{3}{-3} \\
  \verb|$\vecty{0}{0}{0}$|        & \vecty{0}{0}{0}  \\
  \verb|$\vecty{0}{0}{3}$|        & \vecty{0}{0}{3}  \\
  \verb|$\vecty{1}{2}{0}$|        & \vecty{1}{2}{0}  \\
  \verb|$\vecty{0}{3}{3}$|        & \vecty{0}{3}{3}  \\
  \verb|$\vecty{3}{0}{0}$|        & \vecty{3}{0}{0}  \\
  \verb|$\vecty{-1}{1}{0}$|       & \vecty{-1}{1}{0} \\[1.5ex]
  \verb|$\vecty{- 1}{ - 1}{+ 0}$| & \vecty{- 1}{ - 1}{+ 0}\\
  \verb|$\vecty{-1}{-1.0}{+2}$|   & \vecty{-1}{-1.0}{+2}\\
  \verb|$\vecty{-0.0}{+0}{0}$|    & \vecty{-0.0}{+0}{0}\\
  \verb|$\vecty{-0}{+x}{y}$|      & \vecty{-0}{+x}{y}\\
  \verb|$\vecty{-x}{+7}{y}$|      & \vecty{-x}{+7}{y}\\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: A null vector must be written as `\vec{0}` to differentiate it from the scalar one `0`. What do you think?

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ: Good point. Have added a comment in the code, and changed the 0 vector to be in bold.

Comment: This is great but what I was trying was something more than you have given me (I appreciate) If I pass the parameter \vecty{1}{-1}{2} then I expect the outcome to look something like this \hat{i}-\hat{j}+2\hat{k}. I dont want the 1 or -1 to be there in the outcome beside i cap and j cap

Comment: @nichas: Have corrected that case.

Comment: I think you want \jmath rather than j.

Answer (score 12):

`\ifcase` catches the  `0 \or 1 \else` and `\ifnum >0` the +/- case

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newcommand\vecty[3]{\ensuremath{%
  \edef\TEMPnum{#1#2#3}\def\TEMPzero{000}%  
  \ifx\TEMPnum\TEMPzero 0\else%  to make Gonzalo happy :-)
    \ifcase#1\or\hat{i}\ifnum#2>0 +\fi
    \else#1\hat{i}\ifnum#2>0 +\else\ifnum#3>0+\fi\fi\fi
    \ifcase#2 \or\hat{j}\ifnum#3>0 +\fi
    \else #2\hat{j} \ifnum#3>0 + \fi\fi
    \ifcase#3 \or\hat{k}
    \else#3\hat{k}\fi%
    \fi}}

\begin{document}

    \vecty{1}{2}{3} and this should display as $\hat{i}+2\hat{j}+3\hat{k}$

    \vecty{0}{3}{-3} then it should show $3\hat{j}-3\hat{k}$

    \vecty{0}{0}{0} then it should show $0$

    \vecty{2}{0}{2} then it should show $2\hat{i}+2\hat{k}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps a little modification so that `\vecty{0}{0}{0}` produces `0`?

Comment: Refering to the question it should do nothing for `\vecty{0}{0}{0}`, which my solution already does. However, it can easily be modified if you want a 0

Comment: Do as you please; I only mentioned to handle that case as a suggestion based on the mathematical meaning.

Comment: Can you ligature the `\hat{i}` and `\hat{j}` to suppress the upper dots?

Comment: @PeterGrill: works for me as seen in the updated output

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ Yes you can, just use `\hat{\imath}` and `\hat{\jmath}`.

Comment: @tohecz: Thanks. I just have learnt a new thing.

Comment: `\vecty{0}{0}{0}` should produce `\vect{0}` rather than `0` that is a scalar.

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ: I suppose that it is not too difficult for you to replace `0` by `\vec{0}` ...

Comment: You made my day Herbert!
Thankyou very much. 
Wish I could get your email id to get some tips in mastering latex and tikz for getting mathematical content in latex or right direction. Anyway thanks!

Comment: What if I pass a real number or a fraction say 1/2 as parameter to vecty?

Comment: How should `1/2` appear`? As fraction, as `1/2` or as `0.5`? that are far different formats.

Comment: @Herbert If I type `\vecty{2}{0}{2}` then there is no plus sign between the terms. I think this is a bug!

Comment: @Geoff: see edited answer

Comment: @Herbert What about `\vecty{-1}{0}{-1}` this prints the -1, shouldn't it be -i-k?

Comment: Also `\vecty{1}{0}{1}` swallows the middle + yet `\vecty{2}{0}{2}` works.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution using lua, it doesn't offer any advantages over Peter's solution above, so I'm simply posting it for comparisons sake (and because I wanted to get some practice with lua).  Compile with lualatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

%\begin{filecontents*}{vectyfunc.lua}
\begin{luacode*}
function vecty_make (x,y,z)
    local basis = {"\\hat{\\mathrm{i}}","\\hat{j}","\\hat{k}"}
    local coeffs = {x,y,z}
    local str = ""
    local num = 0
    for i = 1,3 do
        coeffs[i] = string.gsub(coeffs[i]," ","")
        -- if not empty
        if coeffs[i]~="" then
            -- and if not zero
            if tonumber(coeffs[i])~=0 then
                num = num + 1
                -- then put a + if missing a sign
                if tonumber(coeffs[i]) == 1 then coeffs[i] = "" end
                if tonumber(coeffs[i]) == -1 then coeffs[i] = "-" end
                if string.find(coeffs[i],"^[+-]") == nil then
                        coeffs[i]="+"..coeffs[i]
                end
            -- and append to str
            str = str..coeffs[i]..basis[i]
            end
        end
    end

    if num == 0 then
        tex.sprint("\\vec{0}")
    else
        -- remove first sign if a +
        if string.sub(str,1,1) == "+" then
            str = string.sub(str,2)
        end
    tex.sprint(str)
    end

end
\end{luacode*}
%\end{filecontents*}

%\directlua{dofile("vectyfunc.lua")}

\newcommand{\vecty}[3]{
        \directlua{vecty_make("#1","#2","#3")}
}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{ll}
\verb|$\vecty{1}{2}{3}$|        & \vecty{1}{2}{3}  \\
\verb|$\vecty{0}{3}{-3}$|       & \vecty{0}{3}{-3} \\
\verb|$\vecty{0}{0}{0}$|        & \vecty{0}{0}{0}  \\
\verb|$\vecty{0}{0}{3}$|        & \vecty{0}{0}{3}  \\
\verb|$\vecty{1}{2}{0}$|        & \vecty{1}{2}{0}  \\
\verb|$\vecty{0}{3}{3}$|        & \vecty{0}{3}{3}  \\
\verb|$\vecty{3}{0}{0}$|        & \vecty{3}{0}{0}  \\
\verb|$\vecty{-1}{1}{0}$|       & \vecty{-1}{1}{0} \\
\verb|$\vecty{- 1}{ - 1}{+ 0}$| & \vecty{- 1}{ - 1}{+ 0}\\
\verb|$\vecty{-1}{-1.0}{+2}$|      & \vecty{-1}{-1.0}{+2}\\
\verb|$\vecty{-0.0}{+0}{0}$|      & \vecty{-0.0}{+0}{0}\\
\verb|$\vecty{-0}{+x}{y}$|      & \vecty{-0}{+x}{y}\\
\verb|$\vecty{-x}{+7}{y}$|      & \vecty{-x}{+7}{y}\\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```