# Matrix with labels nested in braces

Tags: matrices

What's the best way to produce a matrix with labels that are nested in braces, like this:
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Thanks to all for the great answers.  For future reference, how should I provide a MWE for a question of this sort?

Comment: Just a document starting from `\documentclass{article}` to `\end{document}` with bare essentials, say with matrix typed in etc. is sufficient. We don't ask for much. You can also check for other questions for examples.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In today's *I have too much free time* episode we will attack a question posted without a MWE. Absence of a MWE gives us the right to go as esoteric as possible hence here is one *Tweak this, tweak that* possibility.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=7mm,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=8mm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=4mm},
]
\matrix (m) [mymatrix/.style={execute at empty cell=
\ifnum\pgfmatrixcurrentrow<5
\ifnum\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn>4
\node\bgroup$0$\egroup;\fi
\else
\ifnum\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn<5
\node\bgroup$0$\egroup;\fi
\fi
},mymatrix,
right delimiter={]},left delimiter={[}]{
&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&\\
};
\begin{scope}[edge from parent path=
{(\tikzparentnode.south) .. controls +(0,-0.2) and +(0,0.2)
.. (\tikzchildnode.north)}]
\node at ([yshift=1.5cm]m.67) {$A$}
child {node {$1$}
child {node {S}}
child {node {I}}}
child {node {$2$}
child {node {S}}
child {node {I}}
};
\node at ([yshift=1.5cm]m.113) {$B$}
child {node {$1$}
child {node {S}}
child {node {I}}}
child {node {$2$}
child {node {S}}
child {node {I}}
};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[edge from parent path=
{(\tikzparentnode.east) .. controls +(0.2,0) and +(-0.2,0)
.. (\tikzchildnode.west)},level distance=6mm,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=9.2mm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=4.5mm}]
\node at ([xshift=-1.6cm]m.152) {$A$}[grow=right]
child {node {$1$}
child {node {S}}
child {node {I}}}
child {node {$2$}
child {node {S}}
child {node {I}}
};
\node at ([xshift=-1.6cm]m.-152) {$B$}[grow=right]
child {node {$1$}
child {node {S}}
child {node {I}}}
child {node {$2$}
child {node {S}}
child {node {I}}
};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Beautiful! TeX is incredible but TeX users are better.

Comment: +1 just for the unknown (at least for me) `execute at empty cell`.

Answer (score 17):

Here's another option using the [`blkarray`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/blkarray) package for the matrix and `\tikzmark` for the braces (using `decoration=brace`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node [anchor=base] (#1) {};}

% for horizontal braces
% \myhbrace{<mark>}{<mark>}{<label>}
\newcommand\myhbrace[3]{%
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt}]   
  (#1.north) -- node[yshift=13pt] {#3} (#2.north);}

% for vertical braces
% \myvbrace{<mark>}{<mark>}{<label>}
\newcommand\myvbrace[3]{%
  \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=6pt,mirror}] 
    ([yshift=3pt]#1.north east) -- node[xshift=-15pt] {#3} ([yshift=3pt]#2.south east);}

\begin{document}

 \[
\begin{blockarray}{ccccccccc}
& \tikzmark{a}S & I\tikzmark{b} & \tikzmark{c}S & I\tikzmark{d} & \tikzmark{e}S 
  & I\tikzmark{f} & \tikzmark{g}S & I\tikzmark{h} \\
\begin{block}{l[cccccccc]}
\\[-1.2ex]
\tikzmark{m}S &  & & & & 0 & 0& 0 & 0 \\[.3ex]
\tikzmark{n}I &  & & & & 0 & 0& 0 & 0 \\[.3ex]
\tikzmark{o}S &  & & & & 0 & 0& 0 & 0 \\[.3ex]
\tikzmark{p}I &  & & & & 0 & 0& 0 & 0 \\[.3ex]
\tikzmark{q}S & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & & & & \\[.3ex]
\tikzmark{r}I & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & & & & \\[.3ex]
\tikzmark{s}S & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & & & & \\[.3ex]
\tikzmark{t}I & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & & & & \\[1ex]
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,baseline]
\myhbrace{a}{b}{$\tikzmark{i}1$}
\myhbrace{c}{d}{$2\tikzmark{j}$}
\myhbrace{e}{f}{$\tikzmark{k}1$}
\myhbrace{g}{h}{$2\tikzmark{l}$}
\myhbrace{i}{j}{$A$}
\myhbrace{k}{l}{$B$}

\myvbrace{m}{n}{$\tikzmark{u}1$}
\myvbrace{o}{p}{$\tikzmark{v}2$}
\myvbrace{q}{r}{$\tikzmark{w}1$}
\myvbrace{s}{t}{$\tikzmark{x}2$}
\myvbrace{u}{v}{$A$}
\myvbrace{w}{x}{$B$}

\node[yshift=15pt,font=\small] at (m|-k) {$i=$};
\node[yshift=2.5pt,font=\small] at (m|-k) {$j=$};
\node[yshift=4pt,font=\small] at (m|-a) {$k=$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code has to be processed three times for the elements to stabilize.

Answer (score 12):

Continuing on in percusse's tradition, here is a slight improvement on the version provided by Gonzalo Medina.

I have used [the `collcell`  package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/collcell) to automate the insertion of the appropriate `\tikzmark` into the matrix.  This makes the matrix a bit more easier to read as it is not cluttered with all the numerous `\tikzmark`s required for this application to yield:

[image]

### Notes:

- I have added an optional first parameter to the `\myhbrace` and `\myvbrace` to allow one to specify the parameters for the `\draw` command.
- Other than the above change, and the manual drawing of the matrix border (see **Further Enhancements** below), the calls to the two brace commands are one to one equivalent to Gonzalo's, with the name changed to something more meaningful (since they are automatically inserted).
- Two new column types are defined here. The first column (and only the first)  must use the `F` column type.  This allows me to recognize when a new row is started.  All others must use the `C` column type.
- Unlike most of the other applications of `\tikzmark`, this
  actually requires three (not two) runs. First two to determine the locations, and the third to do the drawing.
- I have used `newtoggle` from [the `etoolbox` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox) as I prefer that syntax versus the `\newif` syntax. But if you don't want to include an additional package it should be pretty straightforward to adapt this to use `\newif` or [some other conditional methods](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build/33577#33577)
- Similarly, I used [the `xstring` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/) for numerical comparrison, and again this could be done without this package if that was an issue.

### Further Enhancements:

- I am not happy about the fact that I had to manually draw the matrix border. It turns out that the matrix macros do not seem to allow the use of `\newcolumntype`.  I only realized this when I was done with everything else, so was too far into it to not finish it!!

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing}

\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}

% The "F" column type is to ONLY be used for the first column
\newcolumntype{F}{>{\collectcell\NewRowData}{c}<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\collectcell\NewColumnData}{c}<{\endcollectcell}}

\newcounter{RowCount}
\newcounter{ColumnCount}
\newtoggle{DoneWithHeader}
\togglefalse{DoneWithHeader}
\newcommand{\DoneWithHeader}{\global\toggletrue{DoneWithHeader}}

\newcommand*{\NewColumnData}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{ColumnCount}%
    \iftoggle{DoneWithHeader}{}{%
        \tikzmark{Col \arabic{ColumnCount} Left}%
    }{}%
    #1%
    \iftoggle{DoneWithHeader}{}{%
        \tikzmark{Col \arabic{ColumnCount} Right}%
    }%
}%
\newcommand*{\NewRowData}[1]{%
    \IfEq{\arabic{ColumnCount}}{0}{}{\DoneWithHeader}%
    \setcounter{ColumnCount}{-1}% start a new row ==> at first column
    %
    \iftoggle{DoneWithHeader}{%
        \stepcounter{RowCount}%
        \tikzmark{Row \arabic{RowCount}}%
    }{}%
    \NewColumnData{#1}%
}%



\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node [anchor=base] (#1) {};}

% for horizontal braces
% \myhbrace[<draw options>]{<mark>}{<mark>}{<label>}
\newcommand\myhbrace[4][]{%
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt}, #1]   
  (#2.north) -- node[yshift=13pt] {#4} (#3.north);}

% for vertical braces
% \myvbrace[<draw options>]{<mark>}{<mark>}{<label>}
\newcommand\myvbrace[4][]{%
  \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=6pt,mirror}, #1] 
    ([yshift=3pt]#2.north east) -- node[xshift=-15pt] {#4} ([yshift=3pt]#3.south east);}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{FCCCCCCCC}
    & S   & I & S & I & S & I & S & I \\
    S &   &   &   &   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\[.3ex]
    I &   &   &   &   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\[.3ex]
    S &   &   &   &   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\[.3ex]
    I &   &   &   &   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\[.3ex]
    S & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   &   &   &   \\[.3ex]
    I & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   &   &   &   \\[.3ex]
    S & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   &   &   &   \\[.3ex]
    I & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   &   &   &   \\[1ex]
\end{array}
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,baseline]
\myhbrace[violet, thick]{Col 1 Left}{Col 2 Right}{$\tikzmark{Col 1-2}1$}
\myhbrace[violet, thick]{Col 3 Left}{Col 4 Right}{$2\tikzmark{Col 3-4}$}
\myhbrace[violet, thick]{Col 5 Left}{Col 6 Right}{$\tikzmark{Col 5-7}1$}
\myhbrace[violet, thick]{Col 7 Left}{Col 8 Right}{$2\tikzmark{Col 7-8}$}
\myhbrace[orange, thick]{Col 1-2}{Col 3-4}{$A$}
\myhbrace[orange, thick]{Col 5-7}{Col 7-8}{$B$}

\myvbrace[red,  thick]{Row 1}{Row 2}{$\tikzmark{Row 1-2}1$}
\myvbrace[red,  thick]{Row 3}{Row 4}{$\tikzmark{Row 3-4}2$}
\myvbrace[red,  thick]{Row 5}{Row 6}{$\tikzmark{Row 5-6}1$}
\myvbrace[red,  thick]{Row 7}{Row 8}{$\tikzmark{Row 7-8}2$}
\myvbrace[blue, thick]{Row 1-2}{Row 3-4}{$A$}
\myvbrace[blue, thick]{Row 5-6}{Row 7-8}{$B$}

\node[yshift=15pt, font=\small] at (Row 1 |- Col 5-7)    {$i=$};
\node[yshift=2.5pt,font=\small] at (Row 1 |- Col 5-7)    {$j=$};
\node[yshift=4pt,  font=\small] at (Row 1 |- Col 1 Left) {$k=$};

% Draw the lines for the matrix
\newcommand*{\XShift}{0.3em}
\newcommand*{\YShift}{0.5ex}

\coordinate (topLeft) at (Col 1 Left);
\coordinate (botLeft) at (topLeft |- Row 8);

\coordinate (topRight) at (Col 8 Right);
\coordinate (botRight) at (topRight |- Row 8);

\draw [black, line width=1.2pt]% Left matrix line
    ([shift={(0.3*\XShift,-\YShift)}]topLeft) --
    ([shift={(-\XShift,-\YShift)}]topLeft)  |- ([shift={(-\XShift,-1.5*\YShift)}]botLeft) 
    -- ++(1.3*\XShift,0);

\draw [black, line width=1.2pt]% Right matrix line
    ([shift={(-0.3*\XShift,-\YShift)}]topRight) --
    ([shift={( \XShift,-\YShift)}]topRight) |- ([shift={( \XShift,-1.5*\YShift)}]botRight)
    -- ++(-1.3*\XShift,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe put it inside a `\begin{bmatrix} ... \end{bmatrix}` or `\left[ \right]` to draw the delimiters with a few `\!` here and there?

Comment: @percusse: It seems that the `matrix` environment do not allow for the use of `\newcolumntype`. I also did try the `\left[ \right]` but that required me to tweak the spacing in between the columns as it would only be applied to the sub-matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to construct that matrix with `{NiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{12}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

$\begin{NiceMatrix}
  &              & &\Block{1-4}{A}&&&&\Block{1-4}{B}\\
  &              & &\Block{1-2}{1}&&\Block{1-2}{2}&&\Block{1-2}{1}&&\Block{1-2}{2}\\
  &              & &S&I&S&I&S&I&S&I\\
  \Block{4-1}{A}
  &\Block{2-1}{1}&S& & & & &0&0&0&0\\
  &              &I& & & & &0&0&0&0\\
  &\Block{2-1}{2}&S& & & & &0&0&0&0\\
  &              &I& & & & &0&0&0&0\\
  \Block{4-1}{B}
  &\Block{2-1}{1}&S&0&0&0&0\\
  &              &I&0&0&0&0\\
  &\Block{2-1}{2}&S&0&0&0&0\\
  &              &I&0&0&0&0\\
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix[{4-4}{11-11}]
  \OverBrace{2-4}{3-7}{}[shorten] 
  \OverBrace{2-8}{3-11}{}[shorten]
  \OverBrace{3-4}{3-5}{}[shorten]
  \OverBrace{3-6}{3-7}{}[shorten]
  \OverBrace{3-8}{3-9}{}[shorten]
  \OverBrace{3-10}{3-11}{}[shorten]
  \SubMatrix{\{}{4-2}{7-2}{.}
  \SubMatrix{\{}{8-2}{11-2}{.}
  \SubMatrix{\{}{4-3}{5-3}{.}[extra-height=-3pt]
  \SubMatrix{\{}{6-3}{7-3}{.}[extra-height=-3pt]
  \SubMatrix{\{}{8-3}{9-3}{.}[extra-height=-3pt]
  \SubMatrix{\{}{10-3}{11-3}{.}[extra-height=-3pt]
\end{NiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]