# Add Overbrace to describe a column of matrix

Tags: equations, amsmath, matrices, ieeetran

I want to add some over-braces to a matrix to get the following output:

[image]

However, this this what I managed to get:

[image]

I don't know how to get the neuron 1 and neuron 2 headings...I was thinking of overbraces but not sure how to use it in this case. The stuff on the right of the matrix is not aligned properly...My equation number is moving to the next line as well..Can anyone help me please.

My code is as follows (I am using amsmath package):

```
    \begin{equation}

    \begin{matrix}
     J
     =
     \begin{bmatrix}
     \frac{\delta e_{1,1}}{\delta w_{1,1}}  & \frac{\delta e_{1,1}}{\delta w_{1,2}} &
     \cdots & \frac{\delta e_{1,1}}{\delta w_{j,1}}  & \cdots \\[0.5em]

     \frac{\delta e_{1,2}}{\delta w_{1,1}}  & \frac{\delta e_{1,2}}{\delta w_{1,2}} & 
     \cdots & \frac{\delta e_{1,2}}{\delta w_{j,1}}  & \cdots \\[0.5em]

     \cdots & \cdots & \cdots &
     \cdots & \cdots \\[0.5em]

     \frac{\delta e_{1,M}}{\delta w_{1,1}}  & \frac{\delta e_{1,M}}{\delta w_{1,2}} & 
     \cdots & \frac{\delta e_{1,M}}{\delta w_{j,1}}  & \cdots \\[0.5em]

     \cdots & \cdots & \cdots &
     \cdots & \cdots \\[0.5em]

     \frac{\delta e_{P,1}}{\delta w_{1,1}}  & \frac{\delta e_{P,1}}{\delta w_{1,2}} & 
     \cdots & \frac{\delta e_{P,1}}{\delta w_{j,1}}  & \cdots \\[0.5em]

     \frac{\delta e_{P,1}}{\delta w_{1,1}}  & \frac{\delta e_{np,2}}{\delta w_{1,2}} &
     \cdots & \frac{\delta e_{P,2}}{\delta w_{j,1}}  & \cdots \\[0.5em]

     \cdots & \cdots & \cdots &
     \cdots & \cdots \\[0.5em]

      \frac{\delta e_{P,M}}{\delta w_{1,1}}  & \frac{\delta e_{P,M}}{\delta w_{1,2}} & 
      \cdots & \frac{\delta e_{P,M}}{\delta w_{j,1}}  & \cdots \\[0.5em]
      \end{bmatrix} %\!\! 
      \begin{aligned}
      &\left.\begin{matrix}
      m = 1  \\[0.5em]
      m = 2  \\[0.5em]
      \cdots \\[0.5em]
      m = M  \\[0.5em]
      \end{matrix} \right\} %
      p = 1\\
      &\begin{matrix}
      \phantom{\cdots}\cdots\\[0.5em]
      \end{matrix}\\ %
      &\left.\begin{matrix}
      m = 1  \\[0.5em]
      m = 2  \\[0.5em]
      \cdots \\[0.5em]
      m = M\\[0.5em]
      \end{matrix}\right\}%
      p = P\\
     \end{aligned}
     \end{matrix}
     \end{equation}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). This to me is a job for `\tikzmark` but I think there are already solutions here that illustrate how to use that.  For instance see: [Matrix with labels nested in braces](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78847/matrix-with-labels-nested-in-braces/).

Comment: I think you need `\partial` instead of `\delta`

Comment: thanks for pointing this out...I didn't even notice this error..

Comment: @PeterGrill: I also thought of TikZ. Do you think there are other non-TikZ based solutions?

Comment: @KevinC: Yeah, pretty sure there are non-Tikz solutions, even probably a pure TeX solution, but IMHO, I am not sure why they would be any better (except perhaps the package overhead).

Comment: @Saed: I think the answers in [How do I label different rows or columns of a matrix using braces?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40/how-do-i-label-different-rows-or-columns-of-a-matrix-using-braces) will adequately address your problem.

Comment: @PeterGrill : Thanks for pointing out TikZ...KevinC the link  u suggested was very helpful....I managed to solve this problem.. thanks again guys :) ...spent ages on this..if not for u guys i would have spent tomorrow as well...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one (TikZ-free) possibility; `\overmat` writes its first argument above the entries enclosed in the second argument; `\bovermat` (in the second example below) acts analogously, but showing an overbrace. I also fixed the alignment of the expressions to the right using some phantoms:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\overmat[2]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{$\smash{\color{white}\overbrace{\phantom{%
    \begin{matrix}#2\end{matrix}}}^{\text{\color{black}#1}}}$}#2}
\newcommand\partialphantom{\vphantom{\frac{\partial e_{P,M}}{\partial w_{1,1}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
 J
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
 \overmat{neuron 1}{\frac{\partial e_{1,1}}{\partial w_{1,1}}  & \frac{\partial e_{1,1}}{\partial w_{1,2}}} &
 \overmat{$\mkern-3.5mu\cdots$}{\cdots} & \overmat{neuron $j$}{\frac{\partial e_{1,1}}{\partial w_{j,1}} & \frac{\partial e_{1,1}}{\partial w_{j,1}}} & \cdots \\[0.5em]
%
 \frac{\partial e_{1,2}}{\partial w_{1,1}}  & \frac{\partial e_{1,2}}{\partial w_{1,2}} & 
 \cdots & \frac{\partial e_{1,2}}{\partial w_{j,1}}  & \cdots \\[0.5em]
%
 \cdots & \cdots & \cdots &
 \cdots & \cdots \\[0.5em]
%
 \frac{\partial e_{1,M}}{\partial w_{1,1}}  & \frac{\partial e_{1,M}}{\partial w_{1,2}} & 
 \cdots & \frac{\partial e_{1,M}}{\partial w_{j,1}}  & \cdots \\[0.5em]
%
 \cdots & \cdots & \cdots &
 \cdots & \cdots \\[0.5em]
%
 \frac{\partial e_{P,1}}{\partial w_{1,1}}  & \frac{\partial e_{P,1}}{\partial w_{1,2}} & 
 \cdots & \frac{\partial e_{P,1}}{\partial w_{j,1}}  & \cdots \\[0.5em]
%
 \frac{\partial e_{P,1}}{\partial w_{1,1}}  & \frac{\partial e_{np,2}}{\partial w_{1,2}} &
 \cdots & \frac{\partial e_{P,2}}{\partial w_{j,1}}  & \cdots \\[0.5em]
%
 \cdots & \cdots & \cdots &
 \cdots & \cdots \\[0.5em]
%
  \frac{\partial e_{P,M}}{\partial w_{1,1}}  & \frac{\partial e_{P,M}}{\partial w_{1,2}} & 
  \cdots & \frac{\partial e_{P,M}}{\partial w_{j,1}}  & \cdots \\[0.5em]
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{aligned}
  &\left.\begin{matrix}
  \partialphantom m = 1  \\[0.5em]
  \partialphantom m = 2  \\[0.5em]
  \cdots \\[0.5em]
  \partialphantom m = M  \\[0.5em]
  \end{matrix} \right\} %
  p = 1\\
  &\begin{matrix}
  \\[-1.67em]\phantom{\cdots}\cdots
  \end{matrix}\\ %
  &\left.\begin{matrix}
  \partialphantom m = 1  \\[0.5em]
  \partialphantom m = 2  \\[0.5em]
  \cdots \\[0.5em]
  \partialphantom m = M\\[0.5em]
  \end{matrix}\right\}%
  p = P\\
 \end{aligned}
 \end{matrix}
 \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And a variation with braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\overmat[2]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{$\smash{\color{white}\overbrace{\phantom{%
    \begin{matrix}#2\end{matrix}}}^{\text{\color{black}#1}}}$}#2}
\newcommand\bovermat[2]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{$\smash{\overbrace{\phantom{%
    \begin{matrix}#2\end{matrix}}}^{\text{#1}}}$}#2}
\newcommand\partialphantom{\vphantom{\frac{\partial e_{P,M}}{\partial w_{1,1}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
 J
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
 \bovermat{neuron 1}{\frac{\partial e_{1,1}}{\partial w_{1,1}}  & \frac{\partial e_{1,1}}{\partial w_{1,2}}} &
 \overmat{$\mkern-3.5mu\cdots$}{\cdots} & \bovermat{neuron $j$}{\frac{\partial e_{1,1}}{\partial w_{j,1}} & \frac{\partial e_{1,1}}{\partial w_{j,1}}} & \cdots \\[0.5em]
%
 \frac{\partial e_{1,2}}{\partial w_{1,1}}  & \frac{\partial e_{1,2}}{\partial w_{1,2}} & 
 \cdots & \frac{\partial e_{1,2}}{\partial w_{j,1}}  & \cdots \\[0.5em]
%
 \cdots & \cdots & \cdots &
 \cdots & \cdots \\[0.5em]
%
 \frac{\partial e_{1,M}}{\partial w_{1,1}}  & \frac{\partial e_{1,M}}{\partial w_{1,2}} & 
 \cdots & \frac{\partial e_{1,M}}{\partial w_{j,1}}  & \cdots \\[0.5em]
%
 \cdots & \cdots & \cdots &
 \cdots & \cdots \\[0.5em]
%
 \frac{\partial e_{P,1}}{\partial w_{1,1}}  & \frac{\partial e_{P,1}}{\partial w_{1,2}} & 
 \cdots & \frac{\partial e_{P,1}}{\partial w_{j,1}}  & \cdots \\[0.5em]
%
 \frac{\partial e_{P,1}}{\partial w_{1,1}}  & \frac{\partial e_{np,2}}{\partial w_{1,2}} &
 \cdots & \frac{\partial e_{P,2}}{\partial w_{j,1}}  & \cdots \\[0.5em]
%
 \cdots & \cdots & \cdots &
 \cdots & \cdots \\[0.5em]
%
  \frac{\partial e_{P,M}}{\partial w_{1,1}}  & \frac{\partial e_{P,M}}{\partial w_{1,2}} & 
  \cdots & \frac{\partial e_{P,M}}{\partial w_{j,1}}  & \cdots \\[0.5em]
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{aligned}
  &\left.\begin{matrix}
  \partialphantom m = 1  \\[0.5em]
  \partialphantom m = 2  \\[0.5em]
  \cdots \\[0.5em]
  \partialphantom m = M  \\[0.5em]
  \end{matrix} \right\} %
  p = 1\\
  &\begin{matrix}
  \\[-1.67em]\phantom{\cdots}\cdots
  \end{matrix}\\ %
  &\left.\begin{matrix}
  \partialphantom m = 1  \\[0.5em]
  \partialphantom m = 2  \\[0.5em]
  \cdots \\[0.5em]
  \partialphantom m = M\\[0.5em]
  \end{matrix}\right\}%
  p = P\\
 \end{aligned}
 \end{matrix}
 \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great...Just what I was looking for in the first place... I already managed to solve it using TikZ based on the comments on the  question and [How to Specify two level row and column labels of a matrix by braces?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15825/how-to-specify-two-level-row-and-column-labels-of-a-matrix-by-braces?rq=1)...But I will mark this as answer...not many solutions out there without TikZ...This will be useful to people like me..who never used TikZ before..Thanks again.

Comment: Quick question...What does the xcolor package do here?

Comment: @Saed You're welcome! Yes, TikZ is powerful, but some things can be done without it :-) Regarding your question, the difference between `\overmat` and `\bovermat` is simply that the former typesets the overbace in white color.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `{NiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix` (you need several compilations).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}


\[
 J
 =
 \begin{NiceMatrix}[margin,cell-space-limits=3pt,first-row]
\Block{1-2}{\text{neuron } 1} & & \cdots & \Block{1-2}{\text{neuron } j} \\
 \frac{\partial e_{1,1}}{\partial w_{1,1}}  & \frac{\partial e_{1,1}}{\partial w_{1,2}} &
 & \frac{\partial e_{1,1}}{\partial w_{j,1}} & \frac{\partial e_{1,1}}{\partial w_{j,1}} & \cdots  & m=1 &
 \Block{4-1}{p=1} \\
%
 \frac{\partial e_{1,2}}{\partial w_{1,1}}  & \frac{\partial e_{1,2}}{\partial w_{1,2}} & 
 \cdots & \frac{\partial e_{1,2}}{\partial w_{j,1}}  & \cdots & & m=2\\
%
 \cdots & \cdots & & \cdots &
 \cdots & & \cdots \\
%
 \frac{\partial e_{1,M}}{\partial w_{1,1}}  & \frac{\partial e_{1,M}}{\partial w_{1,2}} & 
 \cdots & \frac{\partial e_{1,M}}{\partial w_{j,1}}  & \cdots & & m=M\\
%
 \cdots & \cdots & \cdots &
 \cdots & \cdots & & \cdots \\
%
 \frac{\partial e_{P,1}}{\partial w_{1,1}}  & \frac{\partial e_{P,1}}{\partial w_{1,2}} & 
 \cdots & \frac{\partial e_{P,1}}{\partial w_{j,1}}  & \cdots & & m=1 & \Block{4-1}{p=P}\\
%
 \frac{\partial e_{P,1}}{\partial w_{1,1}}  & \frac{\partial e_{np,2}}{\partial w_{1,2}} &
 \cdots & \frac{\partial e_{P,2}}{\partial w_{j,1}}  & \cdots & & m=2\\
%
 \cdots & \cdots & \cdots &
 \cdots & \cdots & & \cdots \\
%
  \frac{\partial e_{P,M}}{\partial w_{1,1}}  & \frac{\partial e_{P,M}}{\partial w_{1,2}} & 
  \cdots & \frac{\partial e_{P,M}}{\partial w_{j,1}}  & \cdots & & m = M\\
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix[{1-1}{9-6}]
  \SubMatrix{.}{1-7}{4-7}{\}}
  \SubMatrix{.}{6-7}{9-7}{\}}
\end{NiceMatrix}\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use your matrix but I think my example would help our community.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\[
\begin{array}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\rho_1 } &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\rho_2} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ \ }   & 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\rho_k} \\
%
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\overbrace{\rule{4cm}{0pt}}} &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\overbrace{\rule{4cm}{0pt}}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ \ }   & 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\overbrace{\rule{4cm}{0pt}}} \\[-3pt]
\hline
p(t_1) & \cdots & p^{(\rho_1-1)}(t_1) & p(t_2) & \cdots & 
p^{(\rho_2-1)}(t_2) & \cdots  & p(t_k) & \cdots & 
p^{(\rho_k-1)}(t_k) \\
\hline
\end{array}
\] 

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please add an screenshot of your resulting pdf to your answer? For a fast proof ...