# How to create a column layout from a number of choices?

Tags: macros

I am trying to create a command namely `\twoc` to make a simple two column answer space for a specific question. 
The output should appear like this:

[image]

While my code for the `.tex` file that I will be doing should only be like this using the command `\twoc`:

### Code

```
\Question What comes first?\\
\twoc
\text {apple}
\text {zebra}
\text {girrafe}
\text {dog}
\text {elephant}
\text {chicken}
\text {mouse}
\text {carabao}
```

### Note

The command `\twoc` will automatically divide the text choices even. Example if text choices that are made was 8 then there should be 4 in each column.

Answer (score 2):

With a slightly different syntax, you can use the `multicol` environment from [the `multicol` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) within an `enumerate`d list. The `Question` environment below accepts an optional first parameter to control the number of columns (defaults to a single column if not specified):

[image]

### Note:

- The `resume` feature of [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem) is used to number the questions so that subsequent uses can have numbering continue on from the last question number.
- I have used `newtoggle` from [the `etoolbox` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox) as I prefer that syntax versus the `\newif` syntax. But if you don't want to include an additional package it should be pretty straightforward to adapt this to use `\newif` or [some other conditional methods](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build/33577#33577).
- Similarly, `\IfEq` from [the `xstring` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/) but should be able to do this without a package.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newtoggle{UseMulticolumns}
\newenvironment{Question}[2][1]{%
    \IfEq{#1}{1}{%
        \global\togglefalse{UseMulticolumns}%
    }{%
        \global\toggletrue{UseMulticolumns}%
    }%
    \begin{enumerate}[series=QuestionList,label=\arabic*.,resume=*]
    \item #2
    \begin{enumerate}[label={\protect\rule{1.0em}{0.5pt}}]
    \iftoggle{UseMulticolumns}{\begin{multicols}{#1}}{}%
}{%
    \iftoggle{UseMulticolumns}{\end{multicols}}{}%
    \end{enumerate}%
    \end{enumerate}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{Question}{Which comes first?}
    \item chicken
    \item egg
\end{Question}
\begin{Question}[2]{What comes first?}
    \item apple
    \item zebra
    \item girrafe
    \item dog
    \item elephant
    \item chicken
    \item mouse
    \item carabao
\end{Question}
\begin{Question}[3]{Who shot first?}
    \item Han
    \item Greedo
    \item Chewie
\end{Question}
\end{document}
```

Comment: when i build the code using Geany it did not compile. Instead, it underlines `\begin{Question}{Which comes first?}`. I changed the `Question` to `questions` already still it has errors.

Comment: @kayla: I am not familiar with Geany, but if there was a compilation error, then it would be helpful to know what the error was. You probably need to update packages.  If you are on an older release, I would recommend that you install TexLive 2012.

Comment: i already installed TexLive in Ubuntu. But i compile my work(the aaa.tex) using the document class that i have made (the myclass) that when I use it `\documentclass{myclass}` and I use geany - a text editor to compile my latex file. I installed geany's plugin that supports latex in ubuntu so I can build or compile the file in geany rather than in terminal.