# How do you start out each document?

Tags: templates

As in, do you have a `.tex` file from which you begin every document? This hypothetical file would contain most of the things you use in each document on a regular basis. For example, here's my "template".

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}       % Basics
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     % Inputs
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                        % Inputs
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}               % 1 inch margins
\usepackage[pdfauthor={author},                 % Begin PDF metadata
            pdftitle={title},
            pdfproducer={LaTeX with hyperref},
            pdfcreator={pdflatex}]{hyperref}    % End PDF metadata
\hypersetup{
            colorlinks,                         % Begin setup of link colors
            citecolor=black,
            filecolor=black,
            linkcolor=black,
            urlcolor=black,                     % End setup
            pdfpagemode=UseNone                 % Disables bookmarks sidebar auto appearing
            }

\title{title}
\author{author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Insert body here.
\end{document}
```

I get the feeling that I'm missing some essential packages, but that's what I use to start out each document I make.

Comment: Have you seen [What packages do people load by default in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex)?

Comment: That being said: I don't have a common preamble for documents - it depends on what I need for the specific document

Comment: Some editors use 'wizards' for that. In certain instances you can even set up yourself, what that automatically generated preamble should contain. But I don't think there is a universal, one-size-fits-all variant. And neither should there be one IMHO.

Comment: @cgnieder Thanks for that link! A quick Google search found nothing, so I made a post about it.

Comment: @CountZero I find those "wizards" to be usually quite lackluster in terms of options and helpfulness.

Comment: I would recommend you create a `.sty` file that contains all the packages and settings you desire.  Then, if you come across a slight tweak that a document needs, you can include some [conditional compilation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build) in the `.sty` file.  But you should start off with the bare minimum you need and only add packages as you need them.  If you are going to be doing _any_ math in your documents you should also include `mathtools` package (it already includes `amsmath`). But these should be enough packages to get started.