# Include subsections depending on variables/ifthen

Tags: conditionals, compiling, include

I am making a template for several books. I have a mainfile which includes the .tex files for my chapters. For each book, some chapters are always almost the same except for a few subsections.

How can I define a macro or something to only include this subsection under a specific condition?

It should be like this pseudo code:

```
  type=(A,C) <-- defined at the beginning of each book

  \chapter{blabla}

  if type=B, include: \section{first} 
  \section{second} <-- this is included always
  if type=B,C, include: \section{third}
  if type=A, include: \section{fourth}
```

so only sections second, third and fourth would appear in this particular case. Any idea how to realize that?

Comment: Please, take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build

Comment: Does the linked question help?

Comment: Why not simply a `\includeonly{filename1,filename2,...}` in the preamble?

Comment: Thank you Papiro, the linked question is really helpful!