# How to use If with on variables

Tags: conditionals

I want to create my own documentclass and use some variables for creating titlepages etc with it.

So what's the best way/package for doing this?

the class file:

```
\ProvidesClass{myOwnClass}[v0.1]
\newcommand{\myTitlepage}{
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{flushright}
        \textsf{
            \thisAutor\\
            E-Mail: \href{mailto:\thisEmail}{\thisEmail}\\[2ex]
            \ifdefined{Phone: \thisPhone}
            \today
            }
        \end{flushright}
    \end{titlepage}
}
```

the tex-File:

```
\documentclass{myOwnClass}

% BEGIN_FOLD
% Titel
\newcommand{\thisTitle}{Test}
\newcommand{\thisSubTitle}{a test for \LaTeX}

% Autor
\newcommand{\thisAutor}{Some Name}
\newcommand{\thisEmail}{somename@someprovider.com}
\newcommand{\thisPhone}{}
% END_FOLD

\begin{document}
\myTitlepage
\end{document}
```

You see, there is no phonenumber given. If it is so I don't want to print this row, but if there is a given phone number it want to print it.
What's the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Related Question: [Conditional Typesetting/Build](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build/)

Answer (score 4):

Making users having `\newcommand{\thisAuthor}{Some Name}` is not a good interface.
A better one would be having, in the class file,

```
\newcommand{\Author}[1]{\renewcommand{\phab@Author}{#1}}
\let\phab@Author\phab@required
\newcommand{\Email}[1]{\renewcommand{\phab@Email}{#1}}
\let\phab@Email\@empty
\newcommand{\Phone}[1]{\renewcommand{\phab@Phone}{#1}}
\let\phab@Phone\@empty
```

so that you can have something like

```
\ifx\phab@Phone\@empty
  % do nothing
\else
  Phone: \phab@Phone\\[2ex]
\fi
```

in your definition of `\myTitlepage`. If you give a suitable definition of `\phab@required` you can issue an error if `\Author` is not in the document. In the document you'll type

```
\Author{Some Name}
\Email{somename@someprovider.com}
```

and if `\Phone` doesn't appear or there is `\Phone{}`, nothing will be printed.

Here's an example.

### Class file `myownclass.cls`

```
\ProvidesClass{myownclass}[2014/05/06 v0.1]
\newcommand{\myTitlepage}{%
  \begin{titlepage}
  \raggedleft\sffamily
    {\Large\phab@Title\\}
    \ifx\phab@SubTitle\@empty
    \else
      \vspace{1ex}
      \phab@SubTitle\\
    \fi
    \vspace{4ex}
    \phab@Author\\
    \ifx\phab@Email\@empty
    \else
      E-Mail: \href{mailto:\phab@Email}{\phab@Email}\\[2ex]
    \fi
    \ifx\phab@Phone\@empty
    \else
      Phone: \phab@Phone\\[2ex]
    \fi
    \today
  \end{titlepage}
}

\newcommand{\Title}[1]{\renewcommand{\phab@Title}{#1}}
\newcommand{\SubTitle}[1]{\renewcommand{\phab@SubTitle}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Author}[1]{\renewcommand{\phab@Author}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Email}[1]{\renewcommand{\phab@Email}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Phone}[1]{\renewcommand{\phab@Phone}{#1}}

% Initializations
\newcommand\phab@required[1]{The field `#1' is required}

\newcommand\phab@Title{\phab@required{Title}}
\let\phab@SubTitle\@empty
\newcommand\phab@Author{\phab@required{Author}}
\let\phab@Email\@empty
\let\phab@Phone\@empty

\LoadClass{article}

\AtBeginDocument{\RequirePackage{hyperref}}

\endinput
```

### Document `phab.tex`

```
\documentclass{myownclass}

\Title{Test}
\SubTitle{a test for \LaTeX}

% Author
\Author{Some Name}
\Email{somename@someprovider.com}
\Phone{}
% END_FOLD

\begin{document}
\myTitlepage
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your solution seems to be fine. But I always get the error "\phab@Author undefined. \Author{Some Name}".

Comment: @Phab Did you provide a definition for `\phab@required`? It should go before the definition of `\Author`.

Comment: And when I have \Phone{} (with no number), "Phone:" is still printed.

Comment: How do I have to do this definition in my text?

Comment: @Phab I added a complete example

Comment: Sorry, but even your complete example does not work for me. I copied the code and the first shot was as your output shows. But if I entered a phone number, no phone numer was printed, and if I canceled out the email, "E-Mail:" was still printed.

Comment: It certainly depends on the (missing) "\@empty"

Comment: @Phab Yes, sorry, there was a missing `\@empty`. However, if I remove the `\Email` line, nothing is printed.

Comment: Ok if I comment this lines I want to be empty it works fine. But what if the user just doesn't fill out the line: "\Email{}". In this case I want nothing to be printed. With the actual code I'll get "E-Mail:"