# Next Sibling Operator

Tags: macros, packages

I'm very new to TeX, so I'm not exactly sure what the right terminology is for what I'm asking, so please bear with me!

I have a bunch of LaTeX books that I'm converting to HTML via HeVeA. In the TeX code there is something like this:

```
\csttitle{Part I Title}
\cstsubtitle{Part Subtitle}
```

Then down further I have something like this:

```
\cstchaptertitle{Chapter Title}
\cstsubtitle{Chapter Subtitle}
```

So basically I have `\cstsubtitle{}` for all subtitles, but in my HTML I need to differentiate between a `\cstsubtitle{}` that comes after `\csttitle{}` vs. `\cstchaptertitle{}`.

I know thisn's TeX code, but maybe it will help get my idea across...

I'm wanting this kind of logic in my stylesheet for the first example:

```
if (prevSibling == '\csttitle') {    
  \renewcommand{\cstsubtitle}[1]{
    \@open{div}{class="part cstsubtitle"}#1\@close{div}  
  }
}
```

And this for the second example:

```
if (prevSibling == '\cstchaptertitle') {    
  \renewcommand{\cstsubtitle}[1]{
    \@open{div}{class="chapter cstsubtitle"}#1\@close{div}  
  }
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you just need to toggle a flag after `\csttitle` and `\cstchaptertitle`, and check that flag in `\cstsubtitle`. Below I changed the color of the `\cstsubtitle` based on if it is following a `\csttitle` or a `\cstchaptertitle`.

[image]

### Notes:

- I have used `newtoggle` from [the `etoolbox` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox) as I prefer that syntax versus the `\newif` syntax. But if you don't want to include an additional package it should be pretty straightforward to adapt this to use `\newif` or [some other conditional methods](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build/33577#33577).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{AfterCsTitle}

\newcommand{\csttitle}[1]{\global\toggletrue{AfterCsTitle}\textbf{#1}\par}%
\newcommand{\cstchaptertitle}[1]{\global\togglefalse{AfterCsTitle}\textbf{#1}\par}%

\newcommand{\cstsubtitle}[1]{%
    \iftoggle{AfterCsTitle}{%
        \textcolor{red}{#1}%
    }{%
        \textcolor{blue}{#1}%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}

\csttitle{Part I Title}
\cstsubtitle{Part Subtitle}

\medskip
Then down further I have something like this:
\medskip

\cstchaptertitle{Chapter Title}
\cstsubtitle{Chapter Subtitle}

\end{document}
```