# How to define a show/hidden switch?

Tags: conditionals

I'm preparing some notes, basically some  theorems and their proofs.

I'd like to define a show/hidden switch, so that when it was turned on (to show) , all content are generated into the pdf; if it's turned off(to hide), another pdf is generated, with all theorems shown, but the proofs hidden.

How to do this in latex? My document class is "article".

sorry i don't know what tag shall this belongs to.

Comment: This can be easily done with beamer, if you plan to do some slides, but there is not (at least to my knowledge) any "evident solution" with a document in LaTeX.

Comment: Not clear what yo are asking. Consider adding a minimal example (at least specify document class).

Comment: I think this should be covered by [Conditional typesetting / build](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build).

Comment: Note that @PeterGrill comments implies that you produce two documents: one with the proofs, one without. I don't think there is any possibility to have a "toggle" *inside* a pdf, but you can produce several document, or a document with links to other pages or other documents (typically, the proofs).

Comment: @PeterGrill great! it works like a charm :)

Comment: @Clément right, 2 pdf is what i'm looking to. thx!

Comment: Then @PeterGrill 's comment provides you with an answer