# Is there any analog to #pragma once in (La)TeX?

Tags: macros, conditionals

In `C`, I can write [`#pragma once`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once) as a preprocessor directive at the top of a header file, which tells any compiler that supports it to include the file a maximum of one time per compilation cycle, regardless of how many times I `#include` that header file in the other source files. It is a common alternative to [`#ifndef`/`#define`/`#endif` include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), despite not being an officially documented/supported part of the standard.

La(TeX) has several facilities for so-called "include guards", many of which are outlined in the answers to [Conditional typesetting / build](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build).

My question is: Does there exist (or is there a possibility of) a construct in (La)TeX analogous to `#pragma once` in the `C` language; that is, a directive set on one line of a file which causes that file to be input only one time during the compilation?

### MWE for Testing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mydefs.tex}
%<-- insert magic *#pragma once*-like line here to prevent errors
\newcommand{\foo}{foo}
\newcommand{\baz}{baz}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\input{mydefs}
\input{mydefs}
\foo\ \baz\ test.
\end{document}
```

### Note:

You might say to just use `\providecommand` and be done with it, which is a valid answer. But I would like to know if what I've proposed is possible with (La)TeX, *for science!*

Comment: You could use a flag, and wrap the `\input` command to test first.

Comment: You know that's what `\usepackage` does, I suppose? If you want to do things 'by hand' it's normal to do `\csname myresevedname\endcsname\let\myreservedname\endinput` (if it's not been defined, the `\csname` construct will do nothing important, and on a second pass it will be set up equal to `\endinput`).

Comment: Well, you *can* use `gpp` on LaTeX files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

May be you needn't to deal with the name of the file or with another special identifier at the start ot such file. If I understand your question, you need only simply type `\pragmaonce` at the start of the file.
I've looked to the LaTeX internals and I've found that: if the `\input` is followed by `{`, i. e. `\input{filename}`, then the `\@iinput{filename}` macro is processed. Thus I redefined this macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\let\pragma@iinput=\@iinput
\def\@iinput#1{\xdef\@pragmafile{#1}\pragma@iinput{#1}}
\def\@pragmafile{default}
\def\pragmaonce{%
   \csname pragma@\@pragmafile\endcsname
   \global\expandafter\let \csname pragma@\@pragmafile\endcsname = \endinput
}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents*}{mydefs.tex}
\pragmaonce %<-- insert magic *#pragma once*-like line here to prevent errors
\newcommand{\foo}{foo}
\newcommand{\baz}{baz}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\input{mydefs}
\input{mydefs}
\foo\ \baz\ test.
\end{document}
```

Of course, you have to respect the discipline and to type the `\input` only with braces around filename.

Comment: Very nice! This is basically what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

If you load `mydefs` with `\usepackage`, giving it the `.sty` extension, LaTeX will load it only once. But it will not be available after `\begin{document}`.

The analog of `#pragma once` could be

```
\ifcsname mydefs.tex\endcsname
  \expandafter\endinput
\fi
\expandafter\gdef\csname mydefs.tex\endcsname{loaded}

<code in mydefs.tex>
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `\gdef` instead of `\global\let`?

Comment: @cgnieder Yes, wrong code. Fixed