# How to conditionally draw nodes of a tree in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

I want to draw several trees with tikZ (Version 2.10) which are very similar in the sense that there is a first tree and the others are obtained by ommiting some of the nodes of the first one. I wanted to avoid copy and paste in order to keep things editable. 
So a minimal example of how the result should look like is this:

```
  \begin{tikz}
    \node {eins}
    child{
      node{zwei}
      child{
        node{drei}
      }
    }
    ;
  \end{tikz}


  \begin{tikz}
    \node {eins}
    child{
      child{
        node{drei}
      }
    }
    ;
  \end{tikz}
```

I tried to use the following \newif   \if construct:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newif\ifShow
  \Showtrue
  \node {eins}
   child{
     \ifShow
       node{zwei}
      \fi
      child{
        node{drei}
      }
   }
   ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but it results in the error message "ERROR: Package pgf Error: No shape named  is known." The problem seems to be with the child{node{drei}}. If I remove this part, the conditional drawing of node{zwei} works fine.

Do you have any suggestions how to  conditionally draw tree nodes with TikZ?

Comment: It should work. Can you paste the full code? Also use `tikzpicture` environment instead.

Comment: I agree that it should -- But it DOES NOT WORK and I want to understand why and how to resolve the problem. May there be any dependence on the tikz-version I use. I am not sure which version it is but it is surely not the newest one. (How do I figure out my tikz version?) Anyway, I now created a minimal example that should work but it does not.

Comment: I copied and pasted to my editor and it runs without any problems. If you put `\pgfversion` somewhere outside the tikzpicture environment it shows the version of TikZ/PGF

Comment: Ok, so my TIKZ/PGF-Version is 2.10; @percusse which version do you have?

Comment: I have version 3.00

Comment: Related Question: [Conditional typesetting / build](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build).

Comment: @user136015: Your MWE works for me to. I suggest you upgrade your packages.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Tomorrow I try to figure out whether I can update tikz on the machine I am using

Answer (score 4):

Following Peter's link, I tried a different if then else mechanism. The following code works correctly with tikz 2.10. I guess tikz 2.10 is fairly 
outdated but I add this solution for people like me who have no easy control on the version of their tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newbool{DEBUG}
\booltrue{DEBUG}
%\boolfalse{DEBUG}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {eins}
    child{
      \ifbool{DEBUG}{%IF Debug True
       node{zwei}
       }{%else nothing
       }
      child{
        node{drei}
      }
    }
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```