# Creating a maintenance log on just one table

Tags: tables

Since I couldn't find a topic similar to my question I hereby just post it.

I've created a maintenance log where all steps are described in one big table. The table is filled with different options and useboxes, this is because the maintenance logging depends on the type of product and therefore the parts to maintain.

For example I've a monthly maintenance check and want to have a print out of that same table of that specific product for a year. This I want to do without having to include the table 12 times in the master document that will cause blanc pages before and after each page and defining chapters. Is there an option that defines the amount of tables I can insert in order to have one, so called, 'Master-Table' which can be included from the Master-document or from the part/or chapter-document? I'll be looking forward to your responses!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think, we need more information, a sketch/image

Comment: There are many ways to do this and that depends on your particular application. If you know the possible selections of the data you may want before hand you could adapt a solution from [Conditional typesetting / build](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/).

Comment: If you want more of a database like filtering you could use [the `datatool` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool) which will provide the most flexibility. There are also options using [the `collcell` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/collcell) So, it would be best if composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

Comment: Thanks Christian. I reckon an example would indeed be best. What I want to prevent is countless includes. For example, I've a monthly maintenance check. Want I don't want to have in my Master document is

\begin {document}

% Normal chapter numbering is switched on here
\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\include{Monthly}
\include{Monthly}
\include{Monthly}
\include{Monthly}
\include{Monthly}
\include{Monthly}
\include{Monthly}
\include{Monthly}
\include{Monthly}
\include{Monthly}
\include{Monthly}
\include{Monthly}

\end{document}

Is it possible to include the part "Monthly" 12x?

Comment: Now is a monthly check duable in a master document. But now I'm also thinking about wanting to write a daily checklist in Latex. If I want to compile this for a year it would mean I've to include it for 365 times. That is what I would like to prevent. Looking forward to your replies. :)