# Preprocessing code for cross-compilation of two different projects?

Tags: macros, sectioning

I have two different projects, which are the LaTeX code for English and Greek for the same book.

Does LaTeX support preprocessing code (without using any external tools) that would allow two different compilations on a single project giving two different outputs?

In my old Pascal, I could use something like:

```
{$IFC ENG}
file1eng.p
file2eng.p
{$ELSEC}
file1gr.p
file2gr.p
{$ENDC}
```

If I had set now:

```
{$ENG=1}
```

in my preprocessing file, then the compiled project would parse the english file and produce the output of the english project and vice versa.

Is there a similar facility in LaTeX, that would allow me to control the project flow this way? The number and names of the files on both projects are identical.

Comment: You could use a boolean flag for that. But i think it will be much simpler using a `make` file (or something similar).

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document, this can do the trick.

Comment: @Johannes_B Do you mind giving me an example by using a boolean conditional macro? If you want write it as an asnwer and I will upvote it. Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, please have a look at [Conditional typesetting / build](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33576)