# Multiple ways to expand a macro

Tags: macros

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=2]{Amiri}
\usepackage[fullvoc]{arabluatex}

\newcommand{\tamarbuta}{t\={a} marb\={u}\d{t}ah\xspace}
%\newcommand{\tamarbuta}{\arb{tA'a marbU.taT}\xspace}


\begin{document}

 The principle feminine form is the \tamarbuta.

\end{document}
```

In the above MWE suppose I have hundreds of similar macros to be used in the text. Further suppose I have not decided whether the macro should expand to transliteration form or the original Arabic form. How can I preserve both options so that upon choice one or the other option is executed?

(Obviously, the solution I am looking for is not to comment out "the other half" or vice versa if I happen to choose one option.)

Comment: Do you want to decide that for each occurrence separately or globally? If globally, what you have in your MWE is already good enough: Just keep both definitions and comment out the one you don't want. Theoretically you could also use a bool (like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33576/35864): `\newif\ifalttransl` and then `\ifalttransl \newcommand{\tamarbuta}{A}\else \newcommand{\tamarbuta}{B}\fi` and then you can select one or the other with `\alttransltrue` or `\alttranslfalse`.

Comment: @at moewe I think your solution is the answer I am looking for. Could you kindly turn into an answer please. (Are we allowed to have more than two options?)

Comment: TeXnician's answer also includes my suggestion, so why not accept their solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not really clear, so here are two versions:

- uncommented: a command that upon choice (use of `*`) prints one version or the other
- commented: only one version will be defined depending on a switch. Then you'll always have only one text available (for this version the starred version has to be commented out).

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=2]{Amiri}
\usepackage[fullvoc]{arabluatex}

\usepackage{xspace}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tamarbuta}{s}
    {%
        \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
            t\={a} marb\={u}\d{t}ah%
        }{%
            \arb{tA'a marbU.taT}%
        }%
        \xspace%
    }

%\newif\ifarabic
%\ifarabic
%   \newcommand{\tamarbuta}{\arb{tA'a marbU.taT}\xspace}
%\else
%   \newcommand{\tamarbuta}{t\={a} marb\={u}\d{t}ah\xspace}
%\fi


\begin{document}

 The principle feminine form is the \tamarbuta (\tamarbuta*).

\end{document}
```

Comment: With respect to the commented answer: Are we allowed to have more than two options?

Comment: @blackened So you want a switch for more than two options? You could introduce other options (it's just if/else), but for a more sophisticated answer it would be better to ask another question.

Comment: Just for the record: `arabluatex` is able to output romanized Arabic.  For instance `\arb[trans]{tA' marbU.taT}` prints tāʾ marbūṭah in a very straightforward way. See documentation  sect. 7 on pages 33-38 for more information.