# escape new line

Tags: spacing

I need to escape a new line in latex because I am using a line based pre-processor.

```
I have some text like this
#if some condition
, the 2nd part of the sentence here.
#else
.
#endif
```

I need to make it so that the `.` and `,` are correctly attached to the word `this`.

Comment: Try putting a `%` after `this`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes if you make that an answer then you will get a big ✓I don't think that you need to say anything fancy. May be mention that it comments out the new line character.

Comment: You don't really need to use a pre-processor as you can do that all within TeX: [Conditional typesetting / build](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33576/4301).

Comment: @PeterGrill at the time of starting the project, we struggled with, the conditional stuff in latex. It could not **easily** do what we wanted. May be it is better now (have not checked).