# How does the if-condition work?

Tags: conditionals

How can I use an if conditonal in LaTeX? If the conditon is true I want to execute a code and if not then continue. Sorry for my example code and English. I dont know how to do it.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage,bibliography=totoc,numbers=noenddot,abstract=on,multi,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{ifthen} %Paket einbinden
\newboolean{persoenlich} %Deklaration einer boolschen Variable
\setboolean{persoenlich}{false} %Zuweisung eines Wertes.
```

For your information -> Cross-post https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/23136/wie-funktioniert-eine-if-abfrage-in-latex

Comment: Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build?

Answer (score 3):

There are different possibilities.

Plain style would be:

```
\newif\ifMyIfThingy
```

This defines three macros, `\MyIfThingytrue` to set it to true, `\MyIfThingyfalse` to set it to false and `\ifMyIfThingy`. You can use it the following way:

```
\ifMyIfThingy
  True
\else
  False
\fi
```

There are high level implementations in LaTeX like those provided by `etoolbox`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{MyIfThingy}
\booltrue{MyIfThingy}
\boolfalse{MyIfThingy}
\ifbool{MyIfThingy}{True}{False}

\newtoggle{MyToggleThingy}
\toggletrue{MyToggleThingy}
\togglefalse{MyToggleThingy}
\iftoggle{MyToggleThingy}{True}{False}
```

The difference between toggles and booleans in `etoolbox` are that the bools are
internally build upon `\newif` while the toggles are implemented differently and
only use one macro per toggle.

Then there are LaTeX3 booleans like:

```
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \l_my_bool_thingy_bool
\bool_set_true:N \l_my_bool_thingy_bool
\bool_set_false:N \l_my_bool_thingy_bool

\bool_if:NTF \l_my_bool_thingy_bool
  { True }
  { False }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

But you should only use LaTeX3 booleans if you code in `expl3`...

Answer (score 1):

With `ifthen`, you do

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{persoenlich}}{True}{False}
```

Replace `True` with the code you want to execute if the boolean returns true and similarly for `False`.