# Conditional environment

Tags: macros, environments, conditionals

In a huge document, I would like to use 'env1' or 'env2' environment depending on the value of a global variable 'flagenv'. How could I define an environment 'foo' so that I can write something like :

```
flagenv = 1    % 1 for env1 and 2 for env2
...
\begin{document}
  \begin{foo}        % will be read as \begin{env1}
  ...
  \end{foo}
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX S.E. ! Please rewrite your MWE so that it will be fully compiliable with a simple copy-paste. In your case, please write your `\newenvironment` macro, it will be easier to get help (we will just have to correct your macro). I am not a macro wizzard, but I would also set a new counter (`newcounter`) flagenv. AFAIK, `flagenv=1` is not the proper way to declare a variable in TeX. You could set your flagenv to 1 and use conditionnals depending on the fact that your counter is odd or even.

Comment: Thanks but using the conditionals is the help I am requesting :-)

Comment: Does it depend on the text of env1 ou env2 ? I suppose not ? Say that env1 and env2 are environments I defined, derived from Verbatim environment.

Comment: @Wissme The information that `env1` and `env2` are derived from `Verbatim` is crucial. Can you please give a short example of how you define them?

Comment: If you are just asking about conditionals see [Conditional typesetting / build](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33576/4301).

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
\documentclass{...
\usepackage{...
...
%\newcommand\flagenv{0 }%
\newcommand\flagenv{1 }%
%\newcommand\flagenv{2 }%
%\newcommand\flagenv{3 }%
...
\ifcase\flagenv
⟨ definition of environment foo in case \flagenv=0 ⟩
\or
⟨ definition of environment foo in case \flagenv=1 ⟩
\or
⟨ definition of environment foo in case \flagenv=2 ⟩
\or
⟨ definition of environment foo in case \flagenv=3 ⟩
\else
⟨ definition of environment foo in case \flagenv<0 or \flagenv>3 ⟩
\fi
...
\begin{document}
...
\begin{foo}
...
\end{foo}
...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write `\begin{env1}...\end{env1}` roughly what happens is that LaTeX starts a "group" and then inserts commands `\env1...\endenv1`. So to do this it is enough to make the commands `\foo` and `\endfoo` execute `\env1` and `\endenv1` etc, which is easy to do using the `\letcs` command from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package. In more detail,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newenvironment{env1}{Environment 1\csuse{verbatim*}}{\csuse{endverbatim*}}
\newenvironment{env2}{Environment 2\verbatim}{\endverbatim}

\newcommand\SetFoo[1]{\letcs{\foo}{env#1}\letcs{\endfoo}{endenv#1}}

\begin{document}

   \SetFoo{1}
   \begin{foo}
     My little environment
   \end{foo}

   \SetFoo{2}
   \begin{foo}
     My little environment
   \end{foo}

\end{document}
```

produces the output

[image]

As in the MWE, you can use the command `\SetFoo` to change the meaning of the `foo` environment  as many times as you like in the document, including just once in the preamble. In effect, the `\SetFoo{?}` macro defines the `foo` environment so it needs to be "called" before the first `foo` environment.

In the code above I have shown two different example uses of `verbatim` environments. This might fit your use-case but without knowing more about what you are trying to do this is not guaranteed - this is why it is always better to include as much detail as possible in a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) as part of any question.

*Side note* As a general rule, LaTeX commands should not have numbers in them but, as shown, this works OK for environments although such usage may offend purists.