# transform text from one template to another

Tags: formatting, templates

I use laTex for formatting my papers and I use GIT for version controlling the papers i write, once i have a final cut of the paper i go hunting for suitable conferences. most of these have their own templates ( .tex and other .bbl files)

although i start preparing the content (by copying) from master copy to target template of conference. soon i would end up making changes to the content in target (conference version) of the file and i had to copy back the added changes to master copy. Thus defeating the purpose of version control by manual copying here and there .

Can i have only one master copy of the file and use some scripts to automatically transform into target templates ? so i can have proper version control on master copy.

Or any other productivity tips? how are other solving this problem ?

Comment: any .tex related here ? may be question needs to orient itself to tex

Comment: that was implicit , anyway added now thanks !

Comment: Did you have a look at [git LaTeX and branches workflow](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103244/15717)

Comment: See table 4 of the documentation for the boxhandler package (http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/boxhandler/boxhandler.pdf) for use of conditional compilation.  In the case of that package, it shows how to completely rearrange figure and table placement for different versions (e.g., in text versus collected at end of document).  Your needs may not be so extreme, but conditional compilation (even with different classes) is not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the contents (some text inside of `\begin {document}` and `\end{document}`, without including these commands) have no specific commands for a template style, but only common commands (like `\section`, for example), then:

1. Keep just the contents in one-several separate-s file (for example `Contents.tex`) without making this-these files  complete TeX documents (unless you use `standalone` or `docmute` packages).
   .
2. In every template (a complete document without the contents), include in the body of the document `\input{Contents}` (or may be`\include{Contents}` if the file contain a whole chapter).

After that, each time that you editing the `Contents.tex` all templates will give the new version without additional edits.